# Downloading Xcode from somewhere other than the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, download, xcode10, xcode9.4

I have an issue with my Mac where I basically can't download anything from the App Store because when I try to log in it can't verify my device. I tried every solution found online and took it to the Apple Store where they worked on in for an hour and still couldn't fix it.

Can I get current stable/beta version of Xcode from anywhere beside the App Store? Is it possible to have a friend download it and then give it to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download Xcode 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 and get the DMG file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I'll do ya one better.  Xcode 4.3.2 is available to download for all devs direct from apple.  Simply go [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), click the [View Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) link, login and there you can find nearly every modern version of Xcode and the rest of the DVTs.

Comment: Great answer but the link is not quite right for newer versions. [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/2466193) has up-to-date links.

Comment: This is working for me at 2016, I just downloaded Xcode 8.2

Comment: As of 2017, note that from the first link you'll still end up on the Apple Store. However, the "View Downloads" link in this post still lead to the right page.

Comment: Seems to ask me to log in when I click on that now...

Comment: I found that the verification step is a pop-up window with a 6-digit code you have to enter into the browser. For some reason the pop-up window only stayed visible for a split second so I had to make a video, pause it and copy the number. Very strange, but it worked.

Comment: The first link took me to the app store to download Xcode, but the second one worked!

Comment: this answer requires you to "log in", which obviously is not possible if you do not have an account with Apple.

Answer (score 7):

You can download Xcode 9/10 with Paid (Premium) Apple Developer Account from below links.

> **Xcode 10**
>
> - [Xcode 10 - Beta 6](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_Beta_6/Xcode_10_Beta_6.xip)
>     
>   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10 Beta 6) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta_6/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta_6.dmg)
>     
>   - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10 Beta 6) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10_Beta_6/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10_Beta_6.dmg)
>
> **Xcode 9**
>
> - [Xcode 9.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
> - [Xcode 9.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.3) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.2](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.2) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.2) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.1) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.0.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.0.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.0.1.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.0.1) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.0.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.0.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.dmg)
>
> For non-premium account/apple id: (Download Xcode 9.3.x without Paid (Premium) Apple Developer Account from below link)
>
> - [Xcode 9.4.1 (Mac App Store Link)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

[Apple Download Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

Comment: Given how popular this question is, it's age, how it's not accepting any new answer, and how apple keep changing it's download location; here's an updated answer as of 2021-05-02. You can download from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/