# How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?

Tags: xcode, dmg

Where does the Mac App Store download the files to under Lion? I need the DMG file in order to repair something in my system, but how can I access that file?

Answer (score 5803, accepted):

You have to [login](https://developer.apple.com/account/) before using any link below.

You can find all Xcode dmg/xip files directly on:

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

In the list below, the newest are on top.

For each minor version (6.3, 5.1, etc.) *only the latest revision* is in the list.

Note. Use `xip -x <xip>` to bypass verification step when unzipping.

**Xcode 15**

- [15.3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15.3/Xcode_15.3.xip) (Requires macOS 14+)
- [15.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15.2/Xcode_15.2.xip) (includes visionOS support)
- [15.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15.1/Xcode_15.1.xip)
- [15.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15.0.1/Xcode_15.0.1.xip)
- [15.0](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_15/Xcode_15.xip) (Requires macOS 13.5+)

<sub>Since 15, Xcode downloads runtimes and simulators on first launch. You no longer need to manually click to do so:</sub>

[image]

---

**Xcode 14**

- [14.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.3.1/Xcode_14.3.1.xip)
- [14.3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.3/Xcode_14.3.xip) (Requires macOS 13.0+)
- [14.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.2/Xcode_14.2.xip)
- [14.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.1/Xcode_14.1.xip)
- [14.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.0.1/Xcode_14.0.1.xip)
- [14.0](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14/Xcode_14.xip) (Requires macOS 12.5+)

**Xcode 13**

- [13.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip)
- [13.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.3.1/Xcode_13.3.1.xip) (Requires macOS 12.0+)
- [13.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2.1/Xcode_13.2.1.xip)
- [13.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.1/Xcode_13.1.xip)
- [13.0](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13/Xcode_13.xip)

**Xcode 12**

- [12.5.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.5.1/Xcode_12.5.1.xip) (requires Apple silicon Mac running macOS 11+, or an Intel Mac running macOS 11+)
- [12.4](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.4/Xcode_12.4.xip) (requires Apple silicon Mac running macOS 11+, or an Intel Mac running macOS 10.5.4+)
- [12.3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.3/Xcode_12.3.xip) (requires Apple silicon Mac running macOS 11+, or an Intel Mac running macOS 10.5.4+)
- [12.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.2/Xcode_12.2.xip)
- [12.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.1/Xcode_12.1.xip)
- [12.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.0.1/Xcode_12.0.1.xip) (Requires macOS 10.15.4+)

**Xcode 11**

- [11.7](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.7/Xcode_11.7.xip)
- [11.6](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.6/Xcode_11.6.xip)
- [11.5](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.5/Xcode_11.5.xip)
- [11.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.4.1/Xcode_11.4.1.xip) (Requires macOS 10.15.2+)
- [11.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.3.1/Xcode_11.3.1.xip)
- [11.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip)
- [11.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.1/Xcode_11.1.xip)
- [11](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11/Xcode_11.xip) (Requires macOS 10.14.4+)

**Xcode 10** (unsupported for iTunes Connect)

- [10.3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.3/Xcode_10.3.xip) (Requires macOS 10.14.3+)
- [10.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.2.1/Xcode_10.2.1.xip) (Requires macOS 10.14.3+)
- [10.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip) (Last version supporting macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra)
- [10](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10/Xcode_10.xip) (Subsequent versions were unsupported for iTunes Connect from March 2019)

**Xcode 9**

- [9.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.4.1/Xcode_9.4.1.xip)
- [9.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.3.1/Xcode_9.3.1.xip)
- [9.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip) (Last version supporting macOS 10.12.6 Sierra)
- [9.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.1/Xcode_9.1.xip)
- [9.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.0.1/Xcode_9.0.1.xip)

**Xcode 8**

- [8.3.3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.3/Xcode8.3.3.xip)
- [8.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.2.1/Xcode_8.2.1.xip) (Last version supporting OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan)
- [8.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.1/Xcode_8.1.xip)
- [8.0](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8/Xcode_8.xip)

**Xcode 7**

- [7.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg)
- [7.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2.1/Xcode_7.2.1.dmg) (Last version supporting OS X 10.10 Yosemite)
- [7.1.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1.1/Xcode_7.1.1.dmg)
- [7.0.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.0.1/Xcode_7.0.1.dmg)

**Xcode 6**

- [6.4](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg)
- [6.3.2](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3.2/Xcode_6.3.2.dmg)
- [6.2](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.2/Xcode_6.2.dmg) (Last version supporting OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks)
- [6.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1.1/xcode_6.1.1.dmg)
- [6.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_6.0.1/xcode_6.0.1.dmg)

**Even Older Versions** (unsupported for iTunes Connect)

- [5.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg) (Last version supporting OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion)
- [5.0.2](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.0.2/xcode_5.0.2.dmg)
- [4.6.3](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.6.3/xcode4630916281a.dmg)
- [4.5.2](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.5.2/xcode4520418508a.dmg)
- [4.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.4.1/xcode_4.4.1_6938145.dmg)
- [4.3.2](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.3.2/xcode_432_lion.dmg)
- [4.2](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_lion_21264/installxcode_42_lion.dmg)
- [4.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion_21263/installxcode_41_lion.dmg)
- [4.0.2](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3/xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)
- [3.2.6](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)
- [3.1.4](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.1.4_developer_tools/xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg)
- [3.0](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.0/xcode_3.0.dmg)
- [2.5](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.5_developer_tools/xcode25_8m2558_developerdvd.dmg)
- [2.4.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.4.1/xcode_2.4.1_8m1910_6936315.dmg)
- [2.3](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_2.3/xcode_2.3_8m1780_oz693620813.dmg)
- [2.2.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_tools_2.2.1/xcode_2.2.1_8g1165_018213632.dmg)
- [1.5](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_v1.5/xcode_tools_1.5_cd.dmg.bin)
- [1.0](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Mac_OS_X/Mac_OS_X_10.3_Build_7B85/7B85_Xcode_CD.dmg)

Comment: use `xip -x <xip>` to bypass verification step and save a lot of time

Comment: For anyone who is essentially just looking for Git support, you don't need to download the full 10 GB + Xcode download, you just need to download the Command Line Tools for Xcode by searching for "Command Line Tools for Xcode" here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: A handy summary of all Xcode Releases, with betas, release numbers, and SDK versions: https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: Another tool to help download Xcode versions is Xcodes: https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/XcodesApp for UI and https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/Xcodes for a CLI

Uses Aria2 for downloading which can speed up your download 10x.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download from here https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode (requires Apple ID to login). Here you'll find new as well as previous/legacy versions of Xcode.

Comment: if you need to download with FOLX, first add the extension on your browser then you can log in with the folx and download it

Comment: I updated the xcode 15 link for now to the paid dev account link . hope we can get another link soon that's not broken

Comment: Please add 15.0.1 too because it fixed font issue in Xcode 15.0