# Xcode download for Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, download, xcode9, xcode10, xcode9.4

Older threads mention that there is a download for Xcode for Snow Leopard listed in the Xcode downloads on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode if you are logged-in as an enrolled iOS developer - but I can't see it.

A comment on this thread has a direct link to the download, but clicking on the link redirects to an "Access Denied" error page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662246/cant-download-xcode-4-for-snow-leopard-anymore

Comment: This link helped me !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can refer to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/346639/is-there-an-xcode-4-2-for-snow-leopard). or if you have a good internet connection, try to download via torrent. here is the link. [link for xcode via torrent](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/6721955/).

Comment: Thanks Alfred. The direct link in that thread still redirects to "Access Denied". Does it work for you? If so perhaps it takes a while for the access control in the Apple Developer "downloads" to be made aware of the account status after paying for a subscription (the confirmation email for the enrollment was received 10 hours ago).

Comment: its works for me, but i can't find any download button. How about the torrent Neil? have you try to download via torrent? I'm using xcode 4.3.2 because i upgraded from snow to lion 3 months ago.

Comment: Yes the torrent might be the only place to access the dmg. I've emailed Apple about the official download link and will post back if there's an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your Required software is available at this link, https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Currently Xcode 4.2 is on 6th page.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note: OS X 10.6.8 (snow leopard) is now TOO OLD to publish an app.**

You need a mac with OS X 10.8 (mountain lion). Apple have not maintained backward compatibility: the minimum versions of Xcode or Application Launcher needed to meet the app store requirements won't run on 10.6.8.

You can develop, test and simulate with your old mac, but ultimately to build and publish your app you'll need a newer Mac.