# Xcode offline install

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

Now the XCode is available through app store.

I have a lab setup of around 20 iMacs and XCode size is around 4 GB. Is there any way I can install it one time and using pendrive or drive copy it to other macs and connect/activate/authorize on respective macs.

There has to be some thing. 
In some thread I saw that we can download it from connect.apple.com. I logged on and saw the .DMGs. But Xcode 4.4.1.dmg is "1.81GB". How it can be.

I don't have that much bandwidth. 4 GB on 10 systems means 40 GB and the time taken too is imp..

Please Guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've managed to compress Xcode significantly over the last year or so, the .dmg you get from the developer portal will be the way you want to go. It only weighs in at 1.81GB and can be copied to as many computers as you want (provided they are intended to be used by members of the dev program). I just checked on the Mac App Store, and they are distributing Xcode 4.4.1 @ 1.6GB.

Additionally, this question will be closed as off topic. Stack Overflow is specifically for programming related questions. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). In the future, if you have similar questions to this you will get better responses on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastva No problem, any time!

Comment: can you provide the download link Sir? What is latest version of XCode?

Comment: finally I get this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file/10335943#10335943