# How do I get XCode to build a project with Objective-C++ in it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++, scintilla

I added the Scintilla framework successfully to my XCode project (i.e. it finds the header files correctly), but because it is written in Objective-C++ it doesn't compile. I get 8 syntax errors because of `::`s. I already found you can't include Objective-C++ from a pure Objective-C file, so I changed the file extension to `mm`. It still gives me the same 8 errors.
I also changed the file type (of the importing file) to `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp`.

The relevant lines of code (with the errors in comments - the line numbers are from the original file, so without the errors in the comments):

**ScintillaView.h**

```
// Line 47-49
@protocol ScintillaNotificationProtocol 
- (void)notification: (Scintilla::SCNotification*)notification; // 4 errors on this line:
                                                                //   1. expected type-specifier
                                                                //   2. expected ')'
                                                                //   3. expected identifier
                                                                //   4. expected ';'
@end
// [snip]
// Line 131
- (void) notification: (Scintilla::SCNotification*) notification;   // The exact same errors.
```

When copying this code I noticed the `::` operator is used a few more times in the file, so somehow the parser is only able to match it succesfully in certain places.

**Once more, this code is not mine, but taken from the Scintilla Cocoa Library.**
(See here for more info: http://www.scintilla.org/)

XCode 3.2.6, Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Xcode 4.2?

Comment: You are the _third_ person asking that, the second asked it yesterday. Please refer to this comment thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127235/erroneous-installation-alert-upon-installing-xcode-3-2-6?noredirect=1#comment149117_127235. @BlackFrog

Comment: Even if your paid Apple Developer account is not current, try this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-xcode-5-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Comment: @BlackFrog Thank you, but 4.2 is the last version supporting Snow Leopard, and the oldest version in the question you linked to is 4.3.2.

Comment: What about posting the errors?

Comment: @uliwitness They aren't relevant, True errors are because some Objective-C++ code is compiled as vanilla Objective-C, which is not possible. It is not my code, but the code in the Scintilla framework, which, by the way, works fine in the test project included in the download of the library.

Comment: @uliwitness I now notice an autocorrect-produced mistake: true=the.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It's spitting out errors. So obviously at least one of them *must* be relevant, or the code would be working. Unless you give us some information, nobody here can guess what is going wrong.

Comment: @uliwitness I messed up the Scintilla Dependency, so I couldn't reproduce the errors for a while. Now I got it, I will post the errors  plus code. (By the way, it's not my code.)

Comment: Where do you include the declarations of Scintilla::SCNotification etc?

Comment: They are in `Scintilla.h` which is included by `ScintillaView.h` which  is included by `AppController.mm`. @Mark

Comment: Lets see exactly how they are called

Comment: @Mark I included `ScintillaView.h` to be able to do `[[ScintillaView alloc] init];`. But I think I solved it, I'm writing an answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
typedef tdSCNotification Scintilla::SCNotification
```

Before the first offending line revealed that there was no type called `SCNotification` in that namespace. So I searched through the included header files (which, luckily, count only three) for `namespace Scintilla {`. It was in the first included header file, `Scintilla.h`. But it looked like this:

```
#ifdef SCI_NAMESPACE
namespace Scintilla {
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef SCI_NAMESPACE
}
#endif
```

So I assumed SCI_NAMESPACE wasn't defined. I added `#define SCI_NAMESPACE` to `Scintilla.h` somewhere online 45 and it worked. Almost. I got another error message:

> Framework not found Scintilla
>   Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

I think this has to do with how I added the framework to my project, so it should be a separate question.