# The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use. Every run

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5.1

I know this is an issue that was already discussed here many times before, But there is now solution for my problem and its really serious.

**Every second time** I try to run the simulator i get get this bothering message:

**"The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use."**

Closing the simulator does not help.

I need to quit Xcode every single time this happens!

I trying restarting my computer several times.

Please help me, I find my self restarting Xcode 50 times a day. This is totally frustrating.

Comment: What version of Xcode, which SDK, what version of OS X, what kind of Mac?

Comment: I ran into similar problem a while ago. Try reinstalling XCode.

Comment: @PaulR Xcode version 5.1.1

Comment: I think , you have many install in ypur system..

Comment: @Khanh Nguyen what is the best bay to reinstalling? just delete the Xcode app by moving it to the garbage, And re-downloading it?

Comment: @Deepesh Sorry, what do you mean by many?

Comment: xcode 5.1 , xcode 5.1.1, xcode 4.6 etc...

Comment: @Deepesh I'm using a brand new mac, I do not think this is the problum

Comment: delete the xcode from your syatem, then again install ...it's last option

Comment: Move XCode to trash, empty it, and check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-xcode-5-and-get-the-dmg-file) out.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, to avoid further problems we will do "complete" procedure.

On iOS Simulator, you must force quit.

In Xcode, press COMMAND + SHIFT + "K" (letter k) keys; to empty the cache of the application and ensure that all works out.

On then quit Xcode (I recommend that you restart your Mac after this procedure done, if the problem persists) 
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out that the developer tools path was set to a different location than the Xcode I was using. So check with

```
xcode-select -p
```

that your dev tools path is set correctly. If not, fix with

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

if you're using the current AppStore version of Xcode (or the appropriate path to your alternate Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

I think it a bug in Xcode 5.1. Update your Xcode and it will resolve your issue

and i use this solution for this issue. "Close all application from background and then run"

To close application from background use

Select simulator then press "Ctrl+Shift+H+H" So it open background task screen in this close all application from background and then run your application from Xcode.

i hope this will solve you lots of time of restarting the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that seems to be working :

- double press CMD+Shift+H (in simulator )
- close All other apps on
  sim.

Works for me. Let me know!:)