# Can I install Xcode 6 on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, xcode6, osx-mavericks

Is possible install Xcode 6 on a Mac running OS X Mavericks or do I need upgrade to Yosemite? With Xcode 5, it was necessary to upgrade from Mountain Lion to Mavericks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install Xcode 6.2 on Maverick provided the OS X version is 10.9.5 at least.

The downloads for older Xcode versions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943

Comment: Do you have a source for your answer of ≥10.9.5?

Comment: I have personally experienced the very problem of installing Xcode 6 on OS X 10.9.3 where I have been asked to upgrade my OS X from 10.9.3 version to install latest Xcode 6.0.

Comment: Xcode 6.2.x still work on 10.9.5, but Xcode 6.3+ requires OS X 10.10, full stop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_-_7.x_.28with_arm64_support.29

Comment: I've confirmed Xcode 6.2 works on Mavericks 10.9.5. The dmg I found from developer.apple.com: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.2/Xcode_6.2.dmg

Answer (score 5):

This page shows the system requirements for each version of Xcode and which SDK version is compatible. The latest version of Xcode that will work on Mavericks is 6.2

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Xcode 6 is supported on Mavericks, providing you are running **Mavericks 10.9.4** or later.

> Xcode 6 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.9.4 or later or 10.10.

<sup>Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html</sup>

Comment: that is true for Xcode 6.0. But 6.3 for instance requires 10.10 and I cannot find an official list with the minimum osX for each Xcode version