# Xcode 6.3: Crash while archiving a project

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3

I have just got Xcode 6.3 installed and immediately receiving a Xcode crash while archiving a project.

And actually, I don't know how to proceed. I cannot push my product to iTunes Connect.

I am also checking if I can roll back to Xcode 6.2.

```
    Process:               Xcode [4677]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3 (7569)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7569000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812135760
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4677]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2015-04-09 22:23:04.523 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11


Time Awake Since Boot: 9100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        12  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7f946daa5ef0 :: NSOperation 0x7f946d9284b0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D570
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff984e6024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001042e0184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff977aa76e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff984e5eed +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8fae581d -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x0000000107029a41 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] (in DVTSourceControl)
  6  0x0000000104f6eb61 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000107020c24 __77-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTSourceControl)
  8  0x00007fff8fb257e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff8fb255b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff8fb24a6c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8fb24543 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 12  0x00007fff944f4c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff944f8365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff944f9ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff944f76b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff94505fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff99dcd637 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 18  0x00007fff99dcb40d start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff984e603c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001042e0184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 194
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff977aa76e objc_exception_throw + 43
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff984e5eed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fae581d -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:] + 84
5   DVTSourceControl                    0x0000000107029a41 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] + 225
6   IDEFoundation                       0x0000000104f6eb61 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 112
7   DVTSourceControl                    0x0000000107020c24 __77-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 5293
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fb257e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fb255b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8fb24a6c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8fb24543 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff944f4c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff944f8365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff944f9ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff944f76b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff94505fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff99dcd637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff99dcb40d start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: I got the exact same problem so I'm following here. I tried to revoke the certificates and generate new ones as well as generating new provisioning profiles. But it keeps crashing. I have tried to archive an Obj-C project and that works perfectly. Seems that it is Swift projects which causes the crash.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of editing your question, please consider writing an answer if you have one. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have no Swift and it's happening to me

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Seems like the problem is when you have an old project with some subprojects under source control while the main one is not.

I have removed from Xcode Preferences source control completely, and it seems did the trick - now archiving works.

To remove your project from Source Control press command+, (or select Preferences from main menu) -> Source Control and uncheck all parameters.

I am following this issue in the developer forums and seems like Apple is aware of the issues.

New projects are not affected.

**EDIT FOR NEW VERSION OF XCODE (6.3.1)**

After installing new version of Xcode yesterday I have enabled Source Control and it works now correctly. Below is my version now:

[image: My version of Xcode]

Comment: Wow. Epic QA fail..., although not a surprise.

Comment: HUGE issue!  Worked for me as well! Apple needs to fix this. BTW: Who else HATES the new "Organizer"?

Comment: Wow. This must be marked as answer! Disabling Source Control in Prefs did the trick for me too.

Comment: This fixed my issues. Went into Xcode preferences and just turned off Source Control completely and the next build worked without crashing.

Comment: Did you mean 6.3.1 instead of 6.1.3 in 'update' caption?

Comment: Victor, yes, of course 6.3.1 - thanks for the notice.

Comment: XCode 8 and i can still see this issue! This soln solves it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a visual that maybe of assistance!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved this crashing bug with the following steps:

- Remove Xcode.app (throw it in the Trash or remove it via Launchpad)
- Restart your Mac
- Reinstall Xcode 6.3 via the Mac App Store

Everything is now back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

My XCode project (which contains multiple sub projects) is entirely unstable in XCode 6.3.  XCode is crashing at random when I'm working with it - never mind just achieving!  I installed 6.2 side-by-side with 6.3 just to have a fallback option (Actually I have like 4 versions of XCode installed!).  Here's an SO link to download full prior versions:

[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Answer (score 0):

XCode 9 Swift 4
if the xcode crash during the Archive please first check which Account you are using for Archive is your Apple Agreement is updated for this Apple Account?, then please update and re Archive Problem Solve