# XCode 6.3 Crashes When Archiving Application

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I have just updated to the lastest XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

Now, when I try to archive our previously working application for distribution purposes we see the message "archive successful" but XCODE crashes immediately after this (where the organizer would normally open).

Anybody have any ideas?

Here are the details from the crash log...

```
Process:               Xcode [88096]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3 (7569)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7569000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812135760
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [88096]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-04-12 10:52:10.085 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        5EF93B73-2BD1-E454-9891-7EB1F8CC17B5


Time Awake Since Boot: 230000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        13  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7f9f87725a70 :: NSOperation 0x7f9f8792a1f0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D570
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension cannot be nil.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8901b024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010765d184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff88aa876e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff8901aeed +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff90f7781d -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x000000010a395a41 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] (in DVTSourceControl)
  6  0x00000001082e6b61 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x000000010a38cc24 __77-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTSourceControl)
  8  0x00007fff90fb77e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff90fb75b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff90fb6a6c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff90fb6543 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 12  0x00007fff8841ec13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff88422365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff88423ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff884216b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff8842ffe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff89254637 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 18  0x00007fff8925240d start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8901b03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010765d184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 194
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88aa876e objc_exception_throw + 43
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8901aeed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff90f7781d -[NSURL(NSURLPathUtilities) URLByAppendingPathComponent:] + 84
5   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010a395a41 -[DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprint saveBlueprintInFolder:options:] + 225
6   IDEFoundation                       0x00000001082e6b61 __96+[IDEArchive _copySCMBlueprintFromWorkspace:toArchiveWithPath:usingFileManager:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 112
7   DVTSourceControl                    0x000000010a38cc24 __77-[DVTSourceControlWorkspace blueprintWithRemoteRepositories:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 5293
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff90fb77e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff90fb75b5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
10  Foundation                          0x00007fff90fb6a6c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff90fb6543 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8841ec13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88422365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88423ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884216b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8842ffe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff89254637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8925240d start_wqthread + 13
```

Answer (score 14):

Seems like the problem is when you have an old project with some subprojects under source control while the main one is not.

I have removed from Xcode Preferences source control completely, and it seems did the trick - now archiving works.

To remove your project from Source Control press command+, (or select Preferences from main menu) -> Source Control and uncheck all parameters.

I am following this issue in the developer forums and seems like Apple is aware of the issues.

New projects are not affected.

Answered from [Xcode 6.3: Crash while archiving a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548538/xcode-6-3-crash-while-archiving-a-project)

Comment: I had the same issue. Removing everything from source control solved it.
Thanks Shefali

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was definitely an issue with XCODE.  We could build the application just fine with commands line tools.

I found a solution that worked though;

I removed my personal settings from xcuserdata in the .xcodeproj and also in the project.xcworkspace

Reloading into XCODE after deleting these settings fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in XCode 6.3. If you want to keep this under source control, upgrade to XCode 6.3.1

From Release notes:

> Archiving a project or workspace that is not under source control but
>   that contains contents under source control does not crash Xcode.
>   (20521089)

Answer (score 0):

XCode 9 Swift 4
if the xcode crash during the Archive please first check which Account you are using for Archive is your Apple Agreement is updated for this Apple Account?, then please update and re Archive Problem Solve