# Is Xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.0 possible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

Is it possible to use Xcode 6.3 but stay with Swift 1.0?
Using the iOS 8.2 SDK does not help, and I could not find any switch for the Swift version ...

EDIT:
I have an extension build in Swift 1.0 which I do not want to touch, but update my main project

Comment: Why would you need to go back to Swift 1.0?

Comment: I don't want to go back - I want to stay

Comment: Stay with the old Xcode, dont update to Xcode 6.3

Comment: @shmim: You do not have to target 8.3! I have a target of 7.0 for my main app and 8.2 for the Watch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're having syntax problem then you can convert it to latest syntax.
Also there is no way of using 1.0 in xcode 6.3

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this will make the review process will Apple painful. I have a WatchKit App in Swift 1.0 and they are very cautious with updates before the Watch launch!

Comment: @dogsgod it's always better to adopt changes, you can't defer 1.2 for long. You have to use it at some point. Moreover you can't keep using xcode 6.2. I don't know how big is this for you but that's the interesting & challenging thing for you.

Comment: I absolutely agree - in general. Right now, there are some time constraints, unfortunately

Comment: Then I suggest you to use xcode 6.2, [you can download dmg form here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/468724).

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Xcode 6.3 comes with Swift 1.2. If you are concerned about compatibility, you can convert your swift 1.0 code into Swift 1.2 using Xcode 6.3
`Edit->Convert->To latest Swift syntax`

Comment: @styler1972: "not guaranteed" is a very positive term for the actual experience :)