# Xcode error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When attempting to run a build on a connected iOS device in Xcode I get the error:

> Could not find Developer Disk Image

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I saw that there was a public beta for Xcode, so I installed it.

One of the new features is that you don't need to have a Developer Program Account Dingus to upload your app directly to your iPhone.

However, on my iPhone 4s, I also did a public beta update to iOS 8.4, problem being, that there's no Developer Disk Image available for it.

Where do I to find it or how can it be fixed?

Comment: Update your XCode

Comment: For people getting this when deploying to Apple TV... update to Xcode 7.3 Beta 2 and install tvOS 9.2.

Comment: It is shown also when using an updated device to run on, but you did not update your xcode version. A newer iOS Version that your xcode doesn't know. As said before, just update your xcode.

Comment: Sometimes its not as easy as updating your version of Xcode! Updating your version of Xcode means your are compiling with a newer version of the SDK but you still might want support for earlier versions. I should be able to use an older version of Xcode and run on a device with a newer version of the OS. This is ridiculous. Sounds like Apple is trying to force people to lose support for older versions of the OS.

Comment: You will get this error when Xcode doesn't support that iOS version. Check iOS version and accordingly install XCode (Both should be latest)

Comment: Ah good, I can only upgrade Xcode, if I upgrade my OS X first.  And there goes my entire afternoon, downloading and installing several gigs of files... all because I stupidly updated my iPhone (to stop it nagging me every bloody day).  Oh, and I can't update my company's MacBook OS as our Symantec anti-virus doesn't support Sierra yet.  So I can't work with my updated iPhone at all with Xcode.  I haaaaaate Apple.

Comment: Did not touch the mac since 1/2 year. Now just tried to start my app for a little 3 second check from XCode. "Could not find Developer Disk Image". Now a lot of hours work will start , trying to update xcode and OS and and and and.... I hate Apple like speaker before. Will cancel development on Apple and concentrate on Android and Windows.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. This looks like a bug from the IDE, I would suggest filling a bug request to Apple here: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Please Check hopefully its help in feature : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815254/8526454

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I am facing the same issue on **Xcode 7.3 or Older version** of your Xcode and my device version is iOS 10 or newer version of your OS.

This error is shown when your Xcode is old and the related device you are using is updated to latest version.

We can solve this issue by following the below steps:

> Method 1:-

- > Right click on **Xcode 7.3 or version of your Xcode**, now select "**Show Package Contents**", "**Contents**", "**Developer**",
  >   "**Platforms**","**iPhoneOS.Platform**", "**Device Support**".
- > Now check there is latest version of developer disk image(folder) like 12.1 or newest version(folder) in your case. Copy the latest
  >   version and Paste in the same Folder Device Support.

### [image]

- > In my case I have 12.1 is the latest folder. Now it will generate the copy of that version like 12.1 copy or newest version(folder)copy
  >   in your case.
- > Now Change the name of copy folder to your latest version of iPhone like. In mine case, I have 12.1(Folder)copy and rename it into 12.4. As you can see in the above screenshot. You can change it according to your latest version of phone. I need it for 12.4 so i just rename the folder to 12.4.
- Now your Xcode has a new developer disk image. Close the finder now,
  and quit your Xcode. Open your Xcode and the error will be gone. Now
  you can connect your latest device to old Xcode versions.

  ```
                        **OR**
  ```

> Method 2:-

First of all, download the latest Xcode Version. No Need to install the latest Xcode.

We can solve this issue by following the below steps:

> - Right click on **Xcode 8** or Newer version of your **Xcode**, select "**Show Package Contents**", "**Contents**", "**Developer**",
>     "**Platforms**", "**iPhoneOS.Platform**", "**Device Support**"
> - Copy the 10.0 folder (or above for later version).
> - Back in **Finder** select **Applications** again
> - Right click on **Xcode 7.3 or version of your Xcode**, now select "Show Package Contents", "Contents", "Developer", "Platforms",
>     "iPhoneOS.Platform", "Device Support"
> - Paste the 10.0 folder (or above for later version).

Now your Xcode has a new developer disk image. Close the finder now, and quit your Xcode. Open your Xcode and the error will be gone. Now you can connect your latest device to old Xcode versions.

OR

> If you can't download the latest Xcode, you can get the latest
>   Developer Disk Image for your Xcode from this link:-
>
> https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files
>
> Thanks to **Yatko**. So that people can download the latest DMGs.

Answer (score 581):

For people who would have similar problems in the future, beware that this problem is fundamentally rooted in the mismatch of your iOS version and [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) version.

Check the compatibility of iOS and Xcode.

Comment: "Check the compatibility of iOS and xcode."  How?  I just ran recommended system updates on both my Mac and iOS device and still getting this issue.  iMac is 10.11.4, iOS is 9.3.1, Xcode is 7.2 how do I know what is out of sync with what?

Comment: Xcode 7.3 includes SDKs for iOS 9.3  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: The error message is really terrible.  "iOS version mismatch, If problem persists, try updating XCode" would be so much more useful.

Comment: I'm having this issue using latest iOS (9.3.2 (13F69)) and latest OS X (10.11.5 (15F34)) + Xcode (Version 7.1 (7B91b)). No updates available.

Comment: Ok, I see now there is Xcode 7.3 (other people have it). Strangely, App Store app didn't notify me about any updates to Xcode being available (as it usually does). So Xcode indeed wasn't the latest.

Comment: But what does one do when there is no matching Xcode version for the current iOS?  For example, at the time of writing the latest version of Xcode is 15.0.1 and ships with iOS 17.0 SDKs.  But the latest version of iOS is 17.1.1.  And the answer here isn't “Xcode beta”, because the current beta is Xcode 15.1 beta 2 which ships with iOS 17.2 beta SDK.

Answer (score 292):

I personally downloaded Xcode 6.4 beta and 7.0 beta and I was very happy to find the solution by searching "8.4" inside the application folder of the 6.4 beta. By doing this, I found the folder `8.4 (12H4125a)` containing the iOS 8.4 image and I copied this folder to the same path of the 7.0 beta. The path is the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

When you will reopen Xcode 7 and choose your device, there will be an error message; just click on `fix issue` and that should do it!

Comment: I am not sure which folder you are talking about, but you only have to copy this folder: "8.4 (12H4125a)" (or whatever firmware image you need), which is located in this path: "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport".

Comment: Thanks @NicolaD.! Also, an alternative to copying the image is to symbolically link to it: `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.4\ \(12H141\) /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

Comment: Another note: You must run the Xcode beta at least once and let it complete the "verifying" step before copying the 8.4 folder, or it will report that it is damaged.

Comment: Could someone please upload 8.4 disk image somewhere so there is no need to download full Xcode 8.4 package. It must be around 13MB.

Comment: Since the Xcode 6.4 is no longer in beta, I wanted to comment and confirm that this process does work identically for this new production version.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Xcode 7.2 beta (7C46I) released today - this does not have the Developer Disk Image for iOS 9.1. I had to copy the directory for "9.1 (13B137)" from the Xcode.app/.../Device Support folder over to the Xcode-beta.app/.../Device Support folder in order to run apps on my iOS 9.1 devices via the Xcode 7.2 beta..

Comment: @DerekLee: 7.2 beta release notes state *'Devices
• Build and Run on devices running iOS 9.1 is not supported in Xcode 7.2 beta. (23224972)'* - Don't you think there's a gotcha with this approach? -> There is no disk image available for the 7.1 release, only a direct update in the store. Could you please send me the 9.1 folder to give it a try. Downloaded 7.1 release 3 times but my mini refuses to install it... - So I have no access to '9.1 (13B137)' for copying it to my 7.2 beta.

Comment: @mramosch: Nice find - I should have checked the release notes. You should be able to run both the GM version of Xcode 7.1 (installable either via download or the App Store) as well as the beta together on the same machine. Not being able to install to a 9.1 device from Xcode 7.2 was really just an inconvenience for me since you can install to a 9.1 device from Xcode 7.1 GM. Sounds like you'd be best to troubleshoot the installation. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: @DerekLee: Finally got 7.1 to install on my mini and managed to copy the missing 9.1 folder from 7.1 into the 7.2 beta packet so that it runs my 9.1 devices without complaint now. But I don't know if they work without any side effects as the release notes state *'Build and Run on devices running iOS 9.1 is not supported in Xcode 7.2 beta'*

Comment: @mramosch - As I mentioned above, I would recommend testing your 9.1 devices using Xcode GM 7.1, and only use the beta for testing against the beta (iOS9.2). Being able to install to a 9.1 device from Xcode 7.2 beta is really just a convenience.

Comment: My situation is Xcode 7.2 and MacOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite).  I downloaded the Xcode 8 Beta (https://developer.apple.com/download/) and copied:
***~/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.3***

 to ***/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/***

 .  This put the DeveloperDiskImage.img in the right place.  Then restarted Xcode 7.2 and suddenly (after clicking "fix errors") it was able to install and debug to my 9.3 device.

Comment: Worked well for me with iOS 10 / Xcode 8 beta 2:

sudo cp -r /Applications/Xcode8-beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5297c\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Answer (score 139):

### This error occurs **when the version of Xcode predates that of the device**.

For example, attempting to run a build on a device running iOS 9.3 in Xcode 7.2 results in this error; `Could not find Developer Disk Image`.

Why an error message that actually describes what the hell is going on can't be provided is beyond me (Apple, I'm looking at you ).

Update to the latest version of Xcode through the App Store or [via direct download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) to guarantee interoperability with connected iOS hardware.

Comment: checked and there's no updates for xcode, but the error is there. then i searched for it, it goes 'update' on me. oh apple, why you do this to me? downloading now, hope it works.

Comment: @joe The AppStore app is total garbage, anyone else having similar problems there's a [debug menu you can activate](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81263)

Comment: i did a direct download as it seemed a better/faster option. then i cant run the latest xcode (7.3) because my osx is 'old' (10.10) and it requires the latest. note to self: update everything or nothing. still not happy, apple.

Comment: See my comment above.  I was able to just steal the 9.3 folder out of the Xcode 8 Beta download, and place it in Xcode 7.2.  This works, at least for now.  It just can save you having to upgrade to El Capitan and Xcode 7.3.1 until you're ready to do so.

Answer (score 113):

If you're using old Xcode and want to run onto devices with new version of iOS, then do this trick. This basically make a symbolic link from iOS Device Support in new Xcode to old Xcode

https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d

For Xcode 9.0 beta and iOS 11.0 beta (**name your `Xcode9.app` for Xcode 9 beta and `Xcode.app` for Xcode 8**)

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0\ \(15A5278f\)" "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you don't want to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode yet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It worked really well and now I can debug on my iOS 10 device from Xcode 7.  This is a life saver for those working on Swift 2.2 projects not ready to upgrade to Swift 2.3 or Swift 3. Thanks!

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: For Xcode 8 beta 4 & iOS 10 beta 4, use following line:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5322e\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Comment: For Xcode 8 beta 5 & iOS 10 beta 5: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5335a\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

Comment: Xcode 8 beta 6 & iOS beta 6: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5339a\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

Comment: If you had Xcode 7 running when you made the softlink, exit out and restart Xcode afterwards.

Comment: I had to use the following command for Xcode 8 and Xcode 7.3.1 `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A345\) "/Applications/Xcode\ 7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`, where I had renamed my Xcode.app file to Xcode 7.app for my Xcode 7 installation. Xcode 8 was called Xcode.app. Note the 14A345. You can check this number on your system by looking in the directory on your Xcode 8 install.

Comment: @user3847320 posted then saw your post :)
to all: follow the above for the release versions that came out yesterday! I did the same thing to get it working

Answer (score 110):

My problem was with Xcode 7 and Xcode 6.4 beta and iOS 8.4 - device not compatible.

In case of the same problem for better understanding how to fix, do next:

1. Go to /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
2. Go to
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSup‌​port/
3. Copy folder iOS 8.4 in another folder

[image]

4. Restart Xcode

Comment: I think I am in similar situation, but I cannot find the 8.4 folder in either path. My iPhone runs a 8.4(12H143) and it says no more updates available. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you can only find iOS 8.4 if you install 6.4 xCode I have both xCode 7  beta and xCode 6.4, if you have only xCode 7 - that's can be a reason why you cant find it

Comment: This solution also works for iOS 9.1 beta and Xcode 7.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "another folder" @Kirill? I'm using iOS 9.1 Xcode 7.0 Beta 6?

Comment: This saved me from a 4GB download to upgrade XCode 7.2 to 7.3

Comment: Working great getting tvOS & iOS 10 Beta working on xcode 7.3, Thanks!

Comment: working great with xcode 7 and the release of xcode 8 & ios10.. great answer even if it might be a bit hacky :) thanks

Answer (score 75):

If you have iOS 9.1 on your phone, just download [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 7.1 beta instead of using GM.

See Apple's response: *[Could not find developer disk image for iOS 9.1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18282)*

Comment: It also works to copy the device folder from Xcode 7.1 version into the GM Xcode 7, as in the @Kirill answer.

Answer (score 61):

I got the same error message *(Couldn't find developer disk image)* after I updated my devices to iOS 9.2, but forgot to update to Xcode 7.2.

So in my case, the **fix was easy:** just update to Xcode 7.2 via Mac App Store.

Comment: What if my AppStore says Xcode already updated to 7.2, but when I open it it still says 7.1.1? T_T

Comment: Open Xcode. Click on the menu item 'Xcode' -> 'About Xcode'. What is the version number? You should see this: Version 7.2 (7C68)

Comment: Nop, I saw 7.1.1. I had to uninstall Xcode and install it again to get the newest version

Comment: Just had a similar issue, @gfpacheco. My issue was I wasn't logged into my  apple account, but the prompt to log in didn't come into focus (because it was already open from elsewhere, but minimized/hidden). I thought I was updating the software, but was not really.

Answer (score 41):

This message appears when your version of Xcode is too old for the device's version of iOS. **Upgrade Xcode to the latest.**

If the App Store doesn't offer an update for Xcode, **upgrade to the latest Mac OS**. In the past, Apple has been rather aggressive about dropping support for past versions of Mac OS X in the latest Xcode.

EDIT: yes, this error started popping up all over again. :) Xcode 7.3.1, which is the latest one that's available for MacOS 10.11 (*El Capitan*), doesn't support iOS 10. You need MacOS Sierra (and possibly a new Mac).

Answer (score 24):

I just got this, and I'm on Xcode 7.2.1... It appeared when I downloaded iOS 9.3. Check your Project -> Base SDK and if it isn't the same or ahead of your device version, then that's the issue. I didn't see anything in the "Updates" section, but when I searched "Xcode" in the App Store it had an update for 7.3.

Upgrading to **iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3 requires [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)** for Xcode to run, and that's why auto update isn't upgrading Xcode versions.

Answer (score 23):

This problem is a **mismatch** of your iOS version and Xcode version.

Example:

You have an iPhone with **iOS 9.3 GM** and your Xcode version is **7.2.1**. This leads to the issue that you have to update your Xcode to **7.3** which includes SDKs and related stuff for **iOS 9.3**.

Comment: If you also gave instructions on how to update Xcode, then this would be the best answer by far, all of the top answers are too specific to a version of xcode.

Answer (score 16):

There actually is a way to deploy to a device running a newer iOS that the particular version of `Xcode` might not actually support.  What you need to do is copy over the folder that contains the Developer Disk Image from the newer version of `Xcode`.

For example, you can deploy to a device running `iOS 9.3` using `Xcode 7.2.1` (which only supports up to `iOS 9.2`) using this method.  Go to the `Xcode 7.3` install and navigate to:

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**

From here, copy over the folder that contains the version you are trying to run on the older version of Xcode (for this example, it's 9.3 with the build number in parenthesis).  Copy this folder over to the other install of Xcode, and now you should be able to deploy to a device running that particular version of iOS.

This will fail, however, if you're utilizing API calls that were specifically added to the newer version of the `SDK`.  In that case, you will be forced to update Xcode.

Comment: Sounds like a great workaround but, unfortunately, doesn’t work with Xcode 9.3.1 and iOS 10 Beta 2 (kAMDMobileImageMounterDeviceLocked error)

Comment: Darn...I haven't tested it yet with later versions of Xcode and the iOS 10 beta.  Maybe this is due to the fact that the version of iOS is in beta?  If not, then we might need another workaround for the future.  My machines are still running Yosemite so I'm going to need to do something soon.

Comment: This was a real lifesaver! Dev phone was upgraded to iOS 9.3, but we still need to test production code in Xcode 7.2.1 while the Swift 3 branch is is in development. Why Apple doesn't at least allow developers to maintain a broader range of device/development versions is beyond me.

Comment: Yeah, that's a similar situation that I used it in. However some people are now reporting that it no longer works with Xcode 8.0 and iOS 10 

Answer (score 12):

I have experienced the same issue:

> **Could not find Developer Disk Image**

My Xcode version was 7.0.1, and I updated my iPhone's version to 9.2, and upon using Xcode I ran into this problem.

The solution is pretty simple: Just download the latest version of Xcode 7.2 [which was released on 8 Dec, 2015](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and install it. Everything works fine for you as it was before.

**Note: The actual problem is your Xcode version is not compatible/outdated with the version on your device.**

Answer (score 7):

This error is shown when your Xcode installation is too old and the related device you are using is **updated to latest version**.

There are multiple ways to solve this issues.

**1. Update your Xcode installation.**

This is by far the simplest method. Just update your Xcode installation to the latest stable version and things would start working again.

**Note**: Please update your OS as well if Xcode doesn't support your current OS. Which brings us to...

**2. Manually copying Device Disk Image. No update needed.**

This is the clever way around. You don't have to update your Xcode installation or your OS for this.

First open the XCode.dmg and select `Show Package Contents.`

**Phase 1: Getting the downloaded Xcode ready.**

Steps:

1. Download the latest Xcode.dmg from Developer portal.
2. Select the downloaded Xcode.dmg and right click on it.
3. In the options, select *Open With* → *DiskImageMounter*.
4. Now in Finder, open the *Xcode* disk.
5. In the disk, right click on *Xcode*.
6. Select *Show Package Contents*.

Now, a new finder window opens. Follow the instructions below to copy the disk image.

**Phase 2: Copying the Developer Disk Image.**

Steps:

1. In the new finder, go to *Contents*.
2. Inside *Contents*, Go to *Developer*.
3. Inside *Developer*, go to *Platform*.
   Now select the desired platform. For our purpose, we are going to update iOS disk image only.
4. Inside *Platform*, go to *Device Support*.
5. Inside *Device Support*, you'll find a lot of disk images. This includes the **latest device disk images** as well.
6. Copy all the folders inside *Device Support*. Select all and then copy.

**Note:** For step 6, You can copy the disk image you want to copy as well, i.e. copy the latest only. It's the last folder in the hierarchy here.

This ends the *Phase 2*, Copying the disk image. Now in the next phase, we will update the developer disk image of our Xcode installed on our device.

**Phase 3: Upadting the Xcode's developer disk image.**

Now, close all the finder windows for faster operation and less confusion.

We are now going to update our Xcode's disk image for iOS Platform.

Steps:

1. Close the Xcode application if it is open.
2. Open a new finder window.
3. Select the primary partition if you have multiple partitions.
4. Go to *Applications*.
5. Find *XCode* and right click on it.
6. Select *Show Package Contents*.

Finder window updates or opens a new window with *Contents* as the main directory.

7. Select *Contents*.
8. Inside *Contents*, select *Developer*.
9. Now, select *Platforms*.

   10. Now, select *iPhoneOS.platform*.
   11. Inside *iPhoneOS.platform*, go to *Device Support*.
   12. Inside *Device Support*, select all the files and *Move to Trash*.

**Note:** SKIP step 12 if you copied only the latest disk image i.e. the last folder in the hierarchy.

Now, Paste the developer disk image we copied from Phase 2 here.

13. Final Step, right click and `Paste` here.

If everything worked properly, your Xcode has new developer disk image. Close the finder now, and open Xcode. The error should be gone by now.

**Reminder:** Don't forget to unmount the Xcode now from finder as well.

Comment: Excellent workaround in case you can't update XCode! Worked perfectly. Probably worth adding a link to how you get the .dmg for XCode directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file

Answer (score 6):

It works, in my case for Xcode from 7.3 TO 7.1. Copy directory 9.2, for iOS device OS 9.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

As others suggested, this issue is caused by an incompatible iOS version (which is higher than the maximum version that Xcode supports). Normally it can be addressed by updating Xcode, but sometimes you may be restricted to do so, hence here's another workaround.

Head to developer.apple.com/downloads (or google similar stuff if this link dies) to grab the newest Xcode `dmg` image manually, and then mount it. If you're doing this already, the new Xcode is not likely working for you, but you can `cp /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/NEW_IOS_VERSION /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` to copy the image you want into the old Xcode you've installed.

Of course it's not guaranteed to work for future versions, but it's definitely worth trying. For me, my iOS version is `9.3.1 (13E238)`, but I copied `9.3 (13E230)`, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

This happens when your Xcode version doesn't have a necessary component to build the application to your target OS. **You should update your Xcode**.

If you are building a new application for a **beta OS version** that no stable Xcode version is able to build, you should download the **newest Xcode beta** version.

I also had this problem. I was using Xcode 7.3 for my iOS 10 beta iPhone,  so I went to install Xcode 8-beta, and I did the following step to **continue using the stable version of Xcode** with new build tool:

Just like [@onmyway133 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37940175/2655063), but more user-friendly is after finish installing the `Xcode 8-beta` version, go to Xcode 7.3 preferences (`Cmd` + `,`), go to the tab locations, change the `Command Line Tools` to `Xcode 8` in the dropdown list.

I successfully built to both iOS simulator 9.3 and my device iOS 10 beta using Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is fundamentally rooted in the mismatch of your iOS version and Xcode version.

Check the compatibility of iOS and Xcode.

Go To Application folder (In finder) -> right click on Xcode -> click on show package contents -> Double click contents folder -> Double click developers folder -> Double click platforms folder -> Double click iPhoneOS.platform folder -> Double click device support folder -> then add latest developer disk image.

Or

Download Latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 10 beta 7, add the following link on the command line:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5339a\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents for iOS 10 (under NDA, but for people that can use it legally...)

- Copying full folder (as other people said) works
- Symbolic link seems not.

This was tested using Xcode 7.3 (std from Store) AND iPhone 6Plus with 10.0 (14A5261v).

Comment: as per beta 6 seems to work:

 `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A5339a\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
          
_pls remember to quit and reopen Xcode_

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue, and I'm on Xcode 7.2.

It appeared when I downloaded iOS 9.3.

Check your Project -> Base SDK and if it isn't the same or ahead of your device version, then that's the issue.

I didn't see anything in the "Updates" section, but when I searched "Xcode" in the App Store it had an update for 7.3. Upgrading to iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3 requires Mac OS X v10.11 (El Capitan) for Xcode to run, and that's why auto update isn't upgrading Xcode versions.

Answer (score 0):

by the way it DOES work even in Xcode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a) adding an image for iOS 11 beta. I added 11.0 (15A5278f) inside

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

and works with my iPhone 7plus with new iOS 11 beta.

Answer (score 0):

New Updates for iOS Device Support file. Don't need to update Xcode.

You just need to add support file to Xcode's DeviceSupport folder.

[iOS 11.3 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/11.3)

[iOS 11.4 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/11.4)

[iOS 12.0 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/12.0)

[iOS 12.1 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/12.1)

[iOS 12.2 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/12.2)

[iOS 12.3 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/12.3)

[iOS 12.3.1 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/12.3.1)

[iOS 13.0 Developer Disk Image](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases/tag/13.0)

Extract the zip and then copy folder.

Paste this folder in this path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Quit the Xcode and restart, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any `iOS` version to support with `iOS DiskImage` to you `Xcode` from [Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image](https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image) repository

1. Download which version you need from specified repository
2. Quit `Xcode`
3. Open `Applications` folder
4. Right click you `Xcode.app` and choose `Show Package Contents` menu
5. Go to `/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
6. Create folder with name specified in repository and put `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg` and `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature` files
7. Run `Xcode`

Disk image must be in folder like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you came here because you experience this issue while using Xamarin Hot Restart from within Visual Studio on Windows, it could look like this:

Launching '' on 'iPhone'...
Connecting iOS Debugger to '' over USB on port 10000...
There is no developer image available to mount on '' with version '15.3', so the app '' will not be launched automatically
Please launch the application '' on the device '' to continue

If this is the case you might have updated your iPhone to a new version and forgot to also update your iTunes installation that you got from the Windows Store.