# xcode 7.0 beta 3 have device issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

i installed xcode 7.0 beta 3 on my macbook pro, but when i run my app on iPad device with ios version 8.4 it give me this issue. 
please anyone have this issue solve for me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-xcode-7-ios-8-4

Comment: yes but i have not installed xcode 6.4 curentely i have installed xcode 6.2 and xcode 7.0 beta 3 @Teddy

Comment: I do not know which Xcode it is on your screenshot but it clearly says that "iPad (unavailable)". That is usually due to incompatible device. What do you see inside "Devices" (shidt+command+2) when you select your ipad?

Comment: Update your xcode 6.2 to 6.4 to resolve this issue

Comment: how to upgrade from xcode IDE  @abrar ul haq

Comment: GO To XCode Preferences > Select Download> here all new updates list will be available for current xcode version

Comment: i have updated my question check this i have no updation for xcode 6.4 @abrar ul haq

Comment: then you have to download xcode 6.4 . SO you can follow this link for xcode 6.4 [https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12]

Answer (score 1):

Its due to absence of sdk for ios 8.4 in your xcode version.To resolve this issue you have two options 
1. Upgrade your xcode 7 beta version to that version which has sdk for ios 8.4
2. Upgrade your device to ios 9 beta version

you can get more information about Xcode 7 from following link...
[Apple discussion forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7698)