# "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, ios9.1

Recently I've been getting the error: "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

I think this happens since I have updated iOS to 9.1 on the iPhone.
How can I fix the problem and make Xcode support iOS 9.1 devices?

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you have? You will need version 7.1 to work with iOS 9.1

Comment: @Paulw11 using 7.0.1

Comment: Then You need to upgrade from the Mac App Store

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309515/1709587), which is the cause of the string of downvotes you've received over the last 24 hours. Don't let them bother you.

Comment: So, what is the definitive answer? @Paulw11

Comment: Calebs answer is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image)

Comment: This is helpful for latest Xcode : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741510/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image-12-0-16a5288q-or-11-4-1-deve

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) I have experienced same issue, my *Xcode version was 7.0.1*, and I updated my *iPhone to version 9.2*, then upon using Xcode, my iPhone was shown in the section of unavailable device. Just like in image below:

[image]

2) But then I somehow managed to select my iPhone by clicking at
Product -> Destination -> Unavailable Device

[image]

3) But that didn't solved my problem, and it started showing:

> Could not find Developer Disk Image

[image]

**Solution) Then finally I downloaded latest version of *Xcode version 7.2* from  [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and everything has worked fine for me.**

**Update:** Whenever version of iPhone device is higher than version of Xcode, you may experience same issue, so you should update your Xcode version to remove this error.

Answer (score 88):

Xcode 7.0.1 and iOS 9.1 are incompatible. You will need to update your version of Xcode via the Mac app store.

If your iOS version is lower then the Xcode version on the other hand, you can change the deployment target for a lower version of iOS by going to the General Settings and under Deployment set your Deployment Target:

[image]

#### Note:

Xcode 7.1 does not include iOS 9.2 beta SDK. Upgraded to Xcode to 7.2 beta by downloading it from the [Xcode website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/).

Comment: Ran into this again, had to upgrade Xcode to Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).

Comment: I have iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.1.1 and i am getting this "Couldn't find disk image" error. Everything is updated to latest versions

Comment: @mladen5. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885080/xcode-7-1-with-ios-9-2-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image.

Comment: in my case, device ios 9.2, xcode 7.1 and mac yosemite.  xcode 7.2 would hang on install.  i updated to mac elcaptain and on reboot xcode 7.2 auto setup. this cleared error “Could not find Developer Disk Image”.  thank you @CalebKleveter whose link provides this solution.

Comment: My scenario is exactly like @tmr I am very much new to iOS development. Why can't iOS app with target version with lower version can be deployed on iPhone with higher version iOS app

Answer (score 20):

I am facing the same issue on `Xcode 7.3 and my device version is iOS 10`.

This error is shown when your `Xcode` is old and the related device you are using is updated to latest version. First of all, install the latest Xcode version.

We can solve this issue by following the below steps:-

> - Open Finder select Applications
> - Right click on Xcode 8, select "Show Package Contents", "Contents", "Developer", "Platforms", "iPhoneOS.Platform", "Device Support"
> - Copy the 10.0 folder (or above for later version).
> - Back in Finder select Applications again
> - Right click on Xcode 7.3, select "Show Package Contents", "Contents", "Developer", "Platforms", "iPhoneOS.Platform", "Device
>     Support"
> - Paste the 10.0 folder

If everything worked properly, your `Xcode` has a new developer disk image. Close the finder now, and quit your `Xcode`. Open your `Xcode` and the error will be gone. Now you can connect your latest device to old `Xcode` versions.

Thanks

Comment: Ma pleasure, and if your answer has been solved. Please vote me. @AlankarMisra

Comment: I also had to restart xcode. nervertheless, an ideal solution as opposed to naively updating xcode.

Answer (score 16):

For the case XCode version is lower than iOS device's image, you can either copy the disk image from other already updated XCode(or maybe the internet) or upgrade your XCode.

The image is a folder with size about over 10MB, and place(find or put it) here under this path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSup‌​port/".

To enter Xcode.app package, hold control key and click on Xcode.app, you will find additional option like show package content or some word similar. Choose this option and you will enter Xcode.app like entering a normal folder.

Hope it's helpful and good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Simply updated Xcode. Solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

To run the project to latest devices from the older versions of Xcode, follow the following steps :

Go To Finder -> Applications -> Right Click on latest Xcode version -> select show package content -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport -> Copy the latest version folder and paste at the same location of your old Xcode i.e in the DeviceSupport folder of your old Xcode.

Then Restart Xcode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop with Xcode 7 on your iOS10 device :
(Note: you can adapt this command to other Xcode and iOS versions)

1. Rename your Xcode.app to Xcode7.app and download Xcode 8 from the app store.
2. Run Xcode 8 once to install it.
3. Open the terminal and create a symbolic link from Xcode 8 Developer Disk Image 10.0 to Xcode 8 Developer Disk Image folder using this command:

   ```
   ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A345\)/ /Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0
   ```

[Source](http://bsn.io/code/reference/2016/08/26/installing-on-ios-10-with-xcode-7/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only if you create in Xcode 7 the directory "10.0" and you have a mistake in your sentence:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0 \(14A345\) /Applications/Xcode_7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Older XCode version has no **developer disk image** for newer iOS version.
If you don't want upgrade XCode you can find 
ready developer disk images for latest versions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39865199/286361