# Could not find Developer Disk Image - Xcode 7.1 beta & iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode

The `iOS 9.2` is 13C5060d (not sure if that is a beta or not, but my device usually gets the latest betas). I'm trying to sideload f.lux per [these instructions](https://justgetflux.com/sideload/):

And when I have to hit `Cmd+R`, I get **Could not find Developer Disk Image**. Anyone had any luck on this `XCode/iOS` combination? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find Developer Disk Image - Xcode 7 - iOS 8.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-xcode-7-ios-8-4)

Comment: @ChrisLoonam not really, in this case it is 9.2.

Comment: I could be wrong, as I've never personally had the issue, but I would assume that the solutions would be similar regardless of the iOS version.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Xcode 7.2 beta : that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. [I posted it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885080/xcode-7-1-with-ios-9-2-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image/33893098#33893098), and posted my own answer too. And then I came across this question. So please look at the link for the answer. Basically you need to download XCode 7.2 beta

XCode 7.1 does not have iOS 9.1 sdk, as clearly mentioned on the [XCode downloads website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you update Xcode or iOS, you also update the other or you will get this error. This also happened for [Xcode 7.0.1 and iOS 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314733/could-not-find-developer-disk-image/33352278#33352278). So update to Xcode 7.2 and you should be good to go.