# Xcode 7.1 with iOS 9.2 Error (Could not find Developer Disk image)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7.1

I have iOS 9.2 (13C71) installed on my iPhone 5, and I'm enrolled as an Apple Developer.

On my Macbook Pro, I have XCode 7.1 and OSX El Capitan.

When I try to run a project on my phone, is gives the error - "Could not find Developer Disk Image".

Does anyone know what's wrong?[image]

Comment: Xcode 7.1.1 included ios 9.2. You are supposed to update your xcode from 7.1 to 7.1.1 .

Comment: i have 7.1.1 and i have the same issue. I am trying to get latest build and this may fix the issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found out the answer. Went to Xcode website. They clearly say that Xcode 7.1 does not include iOS 9.2 beta sdk.

Upgraded my Xcode to 7.2 beta by downloading it from [the Xcode website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

It works now, and I'm able to run the app on my phone :-)

Thanks to [Muhammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900189/muhammad) for the suggestion!

Comment: Or you can find the .dmg on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: None of these answers work for me.  I'm using the latest Xcode and latest SDK

Answer (score 9):

It is worth pointing out that Xcode 7.2 is [available in the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) now. You don't need to go to the Apple Developer site and get a Beta.

Having said that, the basic facts haven't changed. If you want to use Xcode and iOS 9.2, make sure to use Xcode to 7.2 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Mac App Store and:

-Install the latest version of OSX.

-Install the latest version of Xcode (currently 7.2)

-Restart your Mac

Comment: Downloading 'the latest' isn't always a wise strategy with software - as one may run into all kinds of issues that have not been thoroughly tested.  As others have mentioned, the correct thing to do is check the requirements and supported levels first - then download what you really need.