# "Could Not Find Developer Disk Image" Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode is telling me:

> "Could not find developer disk image,"

when I am trying to load the app onto an iPhone 6 running ios 9.2 and my Xcode is Version 7.1 (7B91b)

Comment: You should update your xcode version 7.2, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885080/xcode-7-1-with-ios-9-2-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image)

Answer (score 1):

If you have iOS 9.2 on your phone, just download xcode 7.2 beta instead of using older version.

Upgraded your Xcode to 7.2 beta by downloading it from the [Xcode website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new update of iOS is released, Apple releases a new version of Xcode too. This new version of Xcode contains the developer disk image necessary to run your projects on latest iOS.

The solution to your problem is to update to the latest version of Xcode or copy the developer disk image folder.

Right click on new version of Xcode -> select "Show Package Contents" -> select "Contents" -> select "Developer" -> select "Plateforms" -> select "iPhoneOS.Plateform" -> select "Device Support" -> copy the 10.0 folder.

Right click on your Xcode -> select "Show Package Contents" -> select "Contents" -> select "Developer" -> select "Plateforms" -> select "iPhoneOS.Plateform" -> select "Device Support" -> now paste the disk image folder.

Answer (score 0):

Older XCode version has no developer disk image for newer iOS version. If you don't want upgrade XCode you can find ready developer disk images for latest versions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39865199/286361