# Xcode 7.3.1 with iOS 10 support

Tags: ios, xcode

Now I have an app based on Xcode 7.3.1 which runs fine. But one problem happened when I want to install the app to an iOS 10 device. It is said "Could not find Developer Disk Image". So I find a solution which is this: https://danielemargutti.com/solve-xcodes-could-not-find-developer-disk-image-error-how-to-run-projects-in-ios-10-device-using-xcode-7/

However, there is no 10.0 folder in the "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport". So I found an easy way (looks like) to install both version of 7.3.1 and 8 which is this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-advice-to-install-Xcode-8-beta-alongside-Xcode-Version-7-3-1

The question is how can I only download the 10.0 folder rather than install Xcode 8 and make a link or copy/paste into Xcode 7.3.1? Thanks in advance of any other solutions.

Comment: I think you would be better off to simply migrate to XCode 8. Hacking Codes to do this sort of thing might work for a bit, but it's unreliable and probably more time consuming than upgrading.

Comment: I know. But I need the files to support iOS 10. How can I receive that?

Comment: What files are you talking about. XCode 8 can quite easily read XCode 7 projects. Also notice you are using a beta. IS that 7 or 8. Best thing to do is to delete all betas and XCodes and download a fresh install from the app store.

Comment: @drekka the user is talking about the developer disk image files needed in Xcode 7.x versions in order to run the debug build in iOS 10 devices from Xcode 7.x versions. There are problems when we just go to Xcode and even migrate to 2.3 version. Some projects are on the release and some developers don't want the upgradation as it will be time and cost consuming both.

Comment: This is where you need to be careful when choosing 3rd party APIs that are built in Swift. If the authors have not already upgraded to the latest Swift version or are not intending to, you get hung out to dry. I've upgraded several projects without too may issues. Normally it only takes an hour or two of work to fix any compiler issues. Most of the Swift APIs I use have already upgraded or are working on Swift 3 in branches. Essentially if a developer doesn't want to do the update, I would be dropping their API asap.

Comment: @drekka Again depends on the size and complexity of the project. Not every project is convertible in 1 or 2 hours. Yes, there are some third party dependencies.
Also sometimes user needs to support some old versions for ex iOS 8 which alamofire 4.0 will not and user have to keep the minimum deployment as 9.0. Some corporate contract problems like the support for iOS 8 mentioned in the contract. There can be n number of reasons. But yes, I do support your statement to be updated every time with latest syntax.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have that uploaded on Dropbox

**iOS 10.0**
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg8xp09srnq26l1/10.0%20%2814A345%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 10.1**
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yskuz655j1o5kf7/10.1%20%2814B72%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 10.2**
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6s0sc00i2avovo/10.2%20%2814C89%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 10.3**
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi5m37tc1ng4uqc/10.3%20%2814E269%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 11.0**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqgpy2ehv8p5bkp/11.0%20%2815A372%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 11.1**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b0aijc6za1s9e8/11.1%20%2815B87%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 11.2**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx71nzq1fee21hq/11.2%20%2815C107%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 11.3**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bnwdjb708wkfnh/11.3%20%2815E217%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 11.4**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8cfrwqd911dq9q/11.4%20%2815F79%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 12.0**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/srhjsob2mko52ff/12.0%20%2816A366%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 12.1**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nranvr8wbkbhrqv/12.1%20%2816B91%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 12.2**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f71olf3xe7ek4aw/12.2%20%2816E226%29.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 13.0**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oppt43zousrz7wl/13.0.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 13.1**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h17fyytb8eax0z/13.1.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 13.5**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxxdql5epibpm2o/13.5.zip?dl=0)

**iOS 13.6**
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut8rkxrgq809krq/13.6.zip?dl=0)

**NOTE:** **Swift 2.3** support is not available from **Xcode 8.3** + versions

Go to your Applications -> Xcode 7.x version.
Right Click it and click on **Show Package Contents** and navigate to the path below :-

```
/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

And paste the unzipped folder (iOS 10.0) at the path mentioned above. It will look like this.

[image]

In the Device Support Folder for Xcode 7.3.1 version you currently will be having folders upto 9.3 only. Simply paste this iOS 10 folder there.

Finally, **Quit and Restart** your Xcode and plug in your iOS 10 Device.

Comment: Great Job ... :)  Otherwise download xcode 8.2  Thanks

Comment: oops i need 10.2 (14C92). :(

Comment: @PiyushSanepara 10.2(14c89) is also there. You might be looking for beta one.

Comment: @PiyushSanepara AFAIK we are getting 14c89 developer disk image in xcode 8.2 stable one. My device is too iOS 10.2 14c92 and works well with this image. Xcode 8.2 stable version only has 14c89 one folder.

Comment: can u upload 11.1 zip. Please i need it urgently. because my net is so slow i cant download Xcode 9.1

Comment: @DHEERAJ Done for you

Comment: @mramosch 11.2 version is in beta currently, why don't you try with 11.1 image using xcode 9.1, the stable one

Comment: I am already running 11.2 on my device. Can’t run the latest Xcode on my Mac mini 2010 because it’s not possible to update to Sierra... - instead of downloading the whole Xcode 2 GB myself I thought somebody who’s already downloaded it could send me the disk image which is 6 MB! That would be great...

Comment: @mramosch Uploaded 11.2 beta disk image.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari -> Thanks a lot, very kind of you!

Comment: can u upload 11.2 zip. Please i need it urgently. because my net is so slow i cant download Xcode 9.2

Comment: @DHEERAJ done. The stable 11.2 is uploaded. Check the edit

Comment: Can anyone upload 11.2.1 file?

Comment: @ERbittuu 11.2.1 will run in Xcode 9.2. Use the 11.2 file.

Comment: can u upload 11.3 zip. Please i need it urgently.

Comment: can u upload 12.1 zip. Please i need it urgently.

Comment: can u upload 12.2 Zip file ?

Comment: can you upload iOS 13 zip file?

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder and from its Top menu click on "Go" and then click on "Go to Folder..."

You'll see one prompt and there paste this below line there,

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

- You'll be redirected to "DeviceSupport" folder.
- Now, Download folder from below link and unzipped it

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9nnatiB3jRaElIeDQzWXNzeEU/view?usp=sharing

- Copy and Paste that folder in "DeviceSupport" folder.
- Restart XCode and enjoy :)

Comment: Please do not copy other's answer

Comment: @iAnkit I think by copy he meant that the answer you posted has same contents which I already posted before. Nothing is new except the file storage cloud. Yours drive, mines dropbox. :-)

Comment: I have posted answer in different way, ultimately, goal is same. If I have copied same content then you can say that It is copied.

Comment: @iAnkit Your answer still has bugs. Reason is the path you posted. Not every user has that same path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/... because there might be different versions of Xcode installed (5.x,6.x,7.x) and you assumed that there is only a single xcode with the name as Xcode.app. It can be any other version like Xcode 7.x or Xcode copy or anything. So the path you posted may fail for some users and they might be redirected to the version of Xcode in which they don't want to install the iOS 10 developer image.

Comment: Well, In that case you are supposed to edit the existing answer, Instead of posting a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download **iOS 11** official developer disk image from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0SKYq_SEPH8TG51dzliV2lINFU?usp=sharing)

Unzip & Paste it in

Applications > Right Click on Xcode > Show Package Contents and follow the below directories and restart your XCode.

/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Comment: iOS 11.1 & iOS 11.2 developer disc images uploaded

Comment: 11.2.1 is available?