# running app on ios10 from xcode 7.3, app appears bigger

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have an iphone 5s running ios 9.3 and an iphone 6 running 9.3 two days back and ios 10 now. When i updated my iphone 6 to ios 10 and tested the app by dragging the app file to the devices folder in xcode 7.3 (generic build) the app appeared bigger for example if a tableview was displaying 10 rows in iphone 5s 9.3 and 12 rows in iphone 6 ios 9.3 it was now displaying 10 rows in iphone 6 ios 10 (the less amount of rows were compensated by the content size, pretty much how it appeared on the 5s but bigger to fit the iphone 6 screen). Why is this so ? Is it because the way i built it ? All my layout constraints too are correct. I do not want to shift to xcode 8 since i use additional pods too.

Comment: I never had this. Did the same which you have done but everything seems fine on Xcode 7.3 with developer disk image of iOS 10

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari i didnt do it via developer disk image of ios 10 i just added the iphone device from developer.apple.com (in the provision files). Then just copied the app file from "products" folder to that device in the devices window of xcode. How do i put the disk image of ios 10 ?

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864771/xcode-7-3-1-with-ios-10-support/39865199#39865199