# Device Registration not working on IOS10

Tags: ios

Device token not registering on iOS 10 for App built with IOS9 SDK, Xcode 7.3, swift 2.0

Comment: did you enable push notification in capabilities and import UserNotification framework ? and check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864771/xcode-7-3-1-with-ios-10-support/39865199#39865199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update xcode from 7.3 to atleast 8

Comment: I have developed my project in swift2.0 ,it won't work on Xcode8

Comment: if you open your project (which was built in swift 2.0) with xcode 8, xcode automatically convert into swift 3.

Comment: yeah you are correct but I have used some third party library if i convert it into swift 3 it will create many issues.

Comment: Using Xcode 8, have you tried converting to Swift 2.3 instead?