# iOS 10.0.1 and Xcode Error: "Could not find developer disk image"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I updated to iOS 10.0.1 and cannot deploy my project to the device anymore. It was working right before the update. I believe my Xcode is updated (7.3.1).

Rebooting device and computer does not fix the issue.
Also interesting, in Xcode Settings -> iOS Deployment target -> iOS 9.3 is the higher version available!

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: your device iOS10 that you are update your xcode 8 because xcode 8 is support iOS10 and xcode 7 in only less than or equal iOS 9 support, doesn't support more than iOS 9.

Comment: your xcode version should be xcode 8.0 .. so you need to update your Xcode

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the Xcode 8 available from the Apple website (not the App store)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314733/could-not-find-developer-disk-image/39784941#39784941, you can get your answer from here. Just open this think and at the end you can find the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Xcode(7.3.1) is not updated. update your Xcode [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12/).