# Error related Disk Image Developer

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I try to run my app (from Xcode 6) in my iPhone, there is an error message :

> Could  not find Developer Disk Image

I have both development and distribution certificate in my mac.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find Developer Disk Image - Xcode 7 - iOS 8.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-xcode-7-ios-8-4)

Comment: Check [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Could+not+find+Developer+Disk+Image+Xcode).