# Xcode Update issue

Tags: xcode

I clearly updated Xcode in my Appstore to version 7.2, and it completed the update, but when I open the about Xcode window, it still shows version 7.1.1 Why hasn't it updated? I cant run it into my iPhone devices which is having iOS 9.2 OS..

If i try to run my xcode project in my iphone device (iOS 9.2) it shows an alert  "Could not find developer disk image"

Here i attached the screenshots

[image: appstore screenshot]

[image: xcode about screenshot]

Comment: Click App Store,if you still see update information about XCode,you need to update again,

Comment: I checked app store it doesn`t show any update information.. Everything is updated properly..

Comment: 7.2 does not update 7.1. It installes itself in parallel to the system. Go to your launch pad into the developers group and you find two Xcode icons. The new one is 7.2. 
Then go from there.

Comment: No it shows only one xcode icon.. that is xcode 7.1.1.. In application also i checked only one xcode is there.. but its size is too big.. nearly 9GB

Comment: Delete Xcode, reinstall

Comment: Mate, I've just woken up to the same problem. Apple still hasn't fix this stupid problem. I've ran into same issue in the past but the solution is to delete your Xcode (to be safe), download Xcode from the direct download link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ Don't waste your time downloading from the MacApp Store. I've downloaded it 3 times from the MacApp Store in the past: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215636/xcode-7-1-1-opens-up-as-xcode-7-0-1  and after wasting 4GB of download each time, that's 12 GB total, it still didn't update. Use direct download fixed it.

Comment: Extra note: You might also want to ensure your computer doesn't sleep while using the direct download link download otherwise Apple's other stupid problem of killing the Internet connection to your computer while the computer screen shuts off to sleep, will cause your download to fail. Unlike on Windows, you can lock your computer screen and the downloads still continue. Why's this question voted close? The close box says "...unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." in this case, Xcode fits that criteria.

Comment: Ya i fixed the issue by fixing delete the old xcode and install new one downloaded from the apple website.. Thanks dude.. Zhang

Answer (score 1):

Restart Xcode. If that don't fix - check if you have only one Xcode installed.

Comment: No i have only one xcode only. I checked so many times.. Same issues someone also posted.. My update says xcode 7.2 installed.. but xcode is not running in my iphone device which is having iOS 9.2

Comment: @RajaSasidharan If you have time, you can just delete xCode and download fresh latest version from Store. That will 100% fix :)

Comment: Kindly suggest any idea.. Do i need to uninstall and get new dmg xcode file from apple website.. If it is the only one solution means how to uninstall properly without affect anything from my app..

Comment: Hi, There is no update information in my appstore also. it seems everything is latest update only including xcode..

Comment: @RajaSasidharan Just move xCode from Applications to Trash folder. Your application won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks tier. then again i have to download it from appstore or apple developer site..??

Comment: @RajaSasidharan Doesn't matter, choose what you like most  :)

Comment: Thanks tier.. There is no other solution apart from reinstall. Because i have spend time on download 4gb

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Xcode Preferences** and click on **Locations**

[image: Sample Image]

There you can see command line change that from new to old now try it.

**In that Command line tools there in no 7.2 means you need to reinstall it.**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: There new one only it displays..  Xcode 7.1.1 it shows

Comment: @RajaSasidharan wait i will check it

Comment: Ya thank you Kishore Kumar. One day gone.. i was struggling with this issue.. In my application also i checked only one xcode is there but it size shows nearly 9GB. Launchpad also only one icon is there

Comment: ok if you are run the code or build what it shows @RajaSasidharan

Comment: if i build it is success.. But if i try to run it in my iphone device (iOS 9.2) it shows an alert "Could not find developer disk image"

Comment: @RajaSasidharan did you use distribution profile ?

Comment: i installed first time from appstore xcode 7.1 then copy my project from another machine uploaded developer profile also.. that time it works perfect.. today only i updated xcode 7.2. but in appstore it says xcode 7.2 updated.. if i open xcode it shows only xcode 7.1.1..

Comment: it is not supporting to my iphone device because i updated my iphone device into current version iOS 9.2

Comment: i think your xcode is not update properly ,you need to uninstall and update it again

Comment: or see the likn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-xcode-7-ios-8-4

Comment: ok ok.. i think that might be the issue.. so i have to again download and reinstall.. no other way

Comment: yes @RajaSasidharan once you complete it tell me i like to no the issues frd

Comment: Sure.. Thank you very much support - Kishore Now only start download from apple developer site..

Comment: @RajaSasidharan did your code work

Comment: Now only installation is going on. Once it is done will update you.. - Kishore KUmar

Comment: It is working fine now.. Thank you - Kishore Kurmar

Comment: wow ippo jolly ah work pannunga @RajaSasidharan .....

Comment: Hi post answer for this question.. so i can accept.. Solution is to reinstall the app - Kishore Kumar..

Comment: @RajaSasidharan i have updated my answer bro

Comment: But that is not a right answer.. -Kishore Kumar

Comment: if you click commandline if there is no option for your updated xcode means not updated @RajaSasidharan ,you can check now it

Comment: go to that command line tool now you can see the option of 7.2

Comment: oh ok ok after reinstall you can run the app , i am correct

Comment: @RajaSasidharan its ok no worry you can work ,your problem is solved so you can enjoy