# How to Fix Xcode Error “Could not find Developer Disk Image” on iOS9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to test my app on iOS 9.2 device using Xcode 7.1.1, and getting the error message

> “Could not find Developer Disk Image”.

Googled and found that, this is due to the `Version Mismatch` between Xcode deployment target and iOS version. On Xcode 7.1, I can see the `deployment target` till iOS 9.1 only.

So, I do understand that have to update my Xcode to the 7.2 version for deployment target iOS 9.2. But i don't wanna do the update.

Is there any valid way to test my app using Xcode 7.1 on iOS 9.2 device?

Comment: Refer to this link [Developer Disk Image Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32542267/5362916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it by downloading XCode 7.2 dmg and installed it as a new copy.

or

Uninstall exiting one and directly download new version of xcode from App Store.

Have look on [same thread in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image) .
If you go for update there also some problem have look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268974/xcode-update-issue?lq=1).

Comment: seems like the most viable option is to update XCode to 7.2

Comment: Yes because i have also faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode iOS SDK should not be less that Device iOS SDK you can install app as Internal Tester by TestFlight. or www.diawi.com