# adding IBAction to send an email from my app

Tags: ios, swift, email

I have a contact us page in my app which shows my Facebook, twitter and website pages. I have managed to get them to work properly by linking a IBAction to the button. The code i used below, however i would like to do the same with my email. When the button is pressed i want to open up the email on the phone and the "To" "subject" fields to be already filled in. I don't want to add a email form to my app as that is the only thing I can find info on.
Is there a way i can achieve this?

```
      import UIKit
       import MessageUI

        class SocialViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



     @IBAction func openWeb(sender: AnyObject) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com")!)
   }



   @IBAction func openFB(sender: AnyObject) {

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXXX")!) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXXXXX")!)
} else {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX")!)
}
  }



  @IBAction func openTW(sender: AnyObject) {

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "tw://profile/XXXXXXXXX")!) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/XXXXXXX")!)
} else {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/XXXXXXX")!)
}
  }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a mail with `Swift` through the native mail application add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your class inheritance

And add the following in your action:

```
var mail: MFMailComposeViewController!

let toRecipients = ["test@mail.com"]
let subject = "Subject"
let body = "Your body text"

mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
mail.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
mail.setSubject(subject)
mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)

presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i get 7 errors. for the line                                                                                 mail = MFMailComposeViewController()    value of type 'UIDevice' has no member 'model name'                                                                                        the following 5 lines beginning with mail give the error..... Use of unresolved identifier 'mail'

Comment: Check the update, something went wrong when I typed. @uz7

Comment: Just one error now. on the line  mail.mailComposeDelegate = self  Cannot assign value of type 'SocialViewController' to type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?'

Comment: You have not added MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate yet. Your class declaration should look like this: class SocialViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Comment: That fixed the errors but now the simulator keep crashing when i press the button. Is that because its simulator? and it will work on iOS device?

Comment: What error message do you get? Have you connected your outlet in a correct way to the button?

Comment: working fine now, the mail screen comes up but the "To" and "Body' fields are empty plus the cancel button doesn't take me back to the app for some reason

Comment: Have you tried it on your phone? It seems to be a bug in Xcode.

Comment: no since the new iPhone update my phone is not working in Xcode keeps saying cannot find developer disk image

Comment: Ok, but the code above works perfect. To solve your developer disk image issue check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-xcode-7-ios-8-4 Good luck @uz7