# I am getting the error "Could not find the developer disc image". The Xcode version is Version 7.1 (7B91b)

Tags: xcode7

[image]

I have run my code more than 30 days from this Xcode , with the version number Version 7.1 (7B91b) and several registered iPad in my company , without ever facing this issue. 
I understand the code is gigantic, the compiling takes time , but this issue needs to be resolved for any compiling process to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is faced when your Xcode version is not compatible with your device version.

you have to solve this error with updating latest version. In the most recent update to iOS 9.2, the same problem will occur with Xcode at 7.1; you need to update to Xcode 7.2
Reference:[Xcode error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image/34960064#34960064)
 **NOTE**:

> for the future best way to solve it is to update both your **Xcode**
>   AND **iOS** to the most  recent version.