# "Could not find Developer Disk Image" run error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7

[image]When I try to run an app on connected iPhone I get the error: **"Could not find Developer Disk Image"**
I am **not** registred Apple Developer right now, but you wouldn't need that in xcode 7 would you?
I Just updated xcode to **version 7.2.1** and my iPhone (6 plus) is running **iOS 9.3**

Comment: Please [search on the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Could+not+find+Developer+Disk+Image) before posting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Xcode 7.2.1 currently only supports up to iOS 9.2

9.3 is in beta, and requires Xcode 7.3, which is currently also in beta. You can download from the developer portal. You won't need to be a paid developer to do this.

Comment: Hi,
I have ios 9.3.1 on my iphone and hence I downloaded Xcode 7.3 from the developer portal. However I now get an error saying You have OS X 10.10.5. The application requires OS X 10.11 or later. I went into About This Mac >> Software Updates and it says No updates available. 

How can I start deploying apps to my iphone again now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is update your OS and XCode but if you have some reason to stick with Yosemite 10.10.5 Xcode 7.2.1, You can use [this copy and paste trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image) to [make it work](https://medium.com/@katopz/heres-how-to-debug-ios-9-3-1-via-xcode-7-2-1-dc3a099d54cf#.ti9c0g8il).
Just download Xcode 7.3.1 GM seed and here are files you need to copy and replace the old one.

1. /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/version.plist
2. /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
3. /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.3 (13E230)

This work for me.

Answer (score 2):

[image]To run your project from your latest Xcode version to latest iOS device follow the following steps :

Go To Finder -> Applications -> Right Click on latest Xcode version -> select show package content -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport -> Copy the latest version folder and paste at the same location of your old Xcode i.e in the DeviceSupport folder of your old Xcode.

Then Restart Xcode.

Comment: This is correct advise. Thank you.
Just copy the required platform from the new Xcode to Xcode 7.3.1 and run it.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to running your project on the simulator, when you run it on the device, you must make sure your version of Xcode supports the version of the beta you have (most likely, it would not).

You can easily just check your target and click on the "General" tab.  Under the "Deployment Info" section, select the "Deployment Target" drop-down menu and you will see the versions your version of Xcode supports (as shown below): 
[image: Xcode Deployment Target Dropdown]