# iOS 9.3 beta xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I just got an Apple ID yesterday solely for the purpose to test my Xcode applications on my iPhone. I also upgraded my Xcode to 7.2. I connected my phone to my Macbook Air via usb cable, and tried to select it in the simulator settings. I selected it, and I get this error every time:

[image]

Here's my device specs: My iPhone is running iOS 9.3 Public Beta 6, my Xcode is on 7.2.1 (7C1002), and my Macbook Air is running 10.11.3 (15D21).

What's going on?

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image

Comment: Update to Xcode 7.3 beta or downgrade your iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You need :
- The new OS of MAC : El Capitain
- then, Xcode 7.3 for your Iphone IOS 9.3

good ?