# Suggest any workaround to Enable Developer Options on iOS (preferably 9 and higher) without use of MacOS or Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, testing, appium

I am using Appium to test mobile apps on iOS. I was wondering if there's a way to enable Developer Options on iPhone and iPad using my Windows PC?

There are many applications and testing frameworks (for example, SeeTestAutomation) that are able to activate this option without the use of X-Code or MacOS, so there must be a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Developer Disk Image** needs to be mounted to the Apple mobile device (Xcode does this process automatically when an Apple device is connected to an Apple computer).

You need to install [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) library on your machine, which comes with the `ideviceimagemounter` tool. Also, you need to have the correct DeveloperDiskImage and DeveloperDiskImage.signature that's version is the same as the mobile device's iOS version you are trying to connect with.

To use the `ideviceimagemounter`:

```
ideviceimagemounter <pathToDeveloperDiskImage> <pathToDeveloperDiskImageSignature>
```

In case of multiple devices connected, specify the udid of the device:

```
ideviceimagemounter -u <udid> <pathToDeveloperDiskImage> <pathToDeveloperDiskImageSignature>
```

To get the UDID of the device:

```
idevice_id
```

You can get the DeveloperDiskImage and the Signature of your Apple computer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image):

> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

See this [ubuntu manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ideviceimagemounter.1.html) for more details.