# Is it possible to use Xcode 7.x with devices running iOS 10 beta?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'd like to check my app's performance on devices running iOS10 beta without using the Xcode 8 Beta. The main reasons for this are to a) retain the ability to archive & upload the app to the App Store, and b) share the app's codebase with others using Xcode 7.x. As far as I understand (I could be wrong), you can't use an Xcode beta to upload apps to the App Store.

I've tried sharing the apps with the iOS10 beta devices via TestFlight. Though this does work it doesn't quite solve the problem of being able to do proper testing and debugging on the beta device. Thanks for reading.

Comment: NO. You cannot use xcode 7.x for iOS 10 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but only if you install Xcode 8 along side Xcode 7 (see below) and you connect the iOS 10 device to your computer while running Xcode 8. Once Xcode 8 downloads and processes the iOS 10 device, you will then be able to use the iOS 10 device on that same computer while using Xcode 7.

Rename /Applications/Xcode.app (your Xcode 7 installation) to something like /Applications/Xcode7.app. Then install Xcode 8. This way you can have both installed at the same time.

And you are correct that beta tools can't be used to build and submit to the App Store. Near the very end of the beta, Apple will post the GM version of Xcode and will send an email to developers that they are accepting iOS 10 apps. Using the GM version of Xcode 8 you will be able to submit your iOS 10 app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, I just pulled up Xcode 8 (it's called Xcode-beta.app) and ran a simple app on my iOS10 device. Then I closed Xcode 8 and opened Xcode 7 (Xcode.app) and tried to run my main app on the same device. I got a popup that says "Could not find Developer Disk Image." What am I missing?

Comment: Figured it out: I also needed to copy the iOS10 support files from Xcode 8 beta to Xcode 7 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013217/1781058).