# iOS 10 Beta Not Working With Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios10

I am trying to run my app with Xcode 7.3.1 on my iOS 10 beta iphone. But it says "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

How can i run my app?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode error "Could not find Developer Disk Image"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Xcode 8 beta to deploy to an iOS 10 beta device.

You can download the Xcode 8 beta on Apple's developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Once you connect to the iOS device with Xcode 8, you will then be able to use Xcode 7 as well.