# Can I use old frameworks when migrating to Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, xcode8-beta6

I'm currently migrating my project to Swift3 as I know that there is one bug I have under iOS 10 that needs to be fixed.

So I installed iOS 10 on one of my devices.
Now I can't run my app on the device, getting the '[Could not find developer disk image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image)' error.

So I downloaded the latest Xcode8-beta.
Now my code can't be compiled - I first have to convert it to the newest syntax.
So while fixing all the non auto-converted syntax issues, I'm getting errors for frameworks I'm importing, too:
"Module file was created by an older version of the compiler"
Which - to my understanding - means that this framework needs to be recompiled with the current version of XCode.

This would mean that I would have to cross my fingers that all the frameworks I use are up-to-date, or otherwise, fix those, too?

Is it not possible at all to use 'deprecated' frameworks?

Is this Apple being super strict to get rid of any Swift1/2 code as possible?

Answer (score 2):

> This would mean that I would have to cross my fingers that all the frameworks I use are up-to-date, or otherwise, fix those, too?
>
> Is it not possible at all to use 'deprecated' frameworks?
>
> Is this Apple being super strict to get rid of any Swift1/2 code as possible?

Yup. Swift 3 is it.

I feel bad for those that had to convert their C code to swift 2, and now swift 3 is coming xD

Hopefully they will make the transition easier with the final release version, and that shortly after that all of the major frameworks will have been updated (for you to recompile).

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile the frameworks. Even frameworks managed with dependency managers like Carthage (which recompile on each update command) are still having problems with XCode 8 Betas / Swift 3: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1440