# Run old app on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode6, ios10

I have an old application, developed using xCode 6.
I would like to build it and run it on iOS10 without converting the code to a new version of Swift (as it seems taking too long).

Strangely, I am able to run the app on an iPad with iOS 10.0.1 but not on my iPhone which has iOS 10.0.2.
For my iPhone i get ineligible device from the Product>Destination menu.

Does anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify iPhone and iPad versions? I mean for example for iPhone 4s, 5(s), 6(s), 6+, etc.

Comment: iPad 4, iPhone 6S. Thank you

Comment: @MeV, Do you have Xcode 8?

Comment: You can send build to TestFlight and install it to device which have iOS 10. But batter you update your code.

Comment: @MandeepSingh yes I do have it but as soon as I open the project with xCode8 I receive hundreds of errors (I believe because the code is not running the last version of Swift, 3)

Comment: @AshishKakkad thanks, that is my plan but I cannot figure out why I cannot locally build it on my iPhone

Comment: @AshishKakkad what do you mean for greater version? I am able to install to 10.0.1 but not 10.0.2, is this explained anywhere?

Comment: @MeV Please see this link, in the bottom of this link may be you will get your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736932/xcode-error-could-not-find-developer-disk-image/39784892#39784892

Comment: @MandeepSingh amazing, This may be the solution. I need to try this, thank you so much (ps. add this as an answer and I will accept it as right answer)

Comment: @MeV, Am really happy, if your answer has been solved. Happy Coding.