# Xcode 6.3 not running iOS 8.4 - update to 6.4 fails

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3, ios8.3, ios8.4, xcode6.4

I have upgraded my iOS to 8.4, then I tried to run Xcode 6.3, it asks it can't mount the device since it's running 8.4 version (".. running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.") 
When I try to upgrade Xcode to 6.4 - update fails every time with error message (try again using purchases).

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is not a bad question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Delete `/Applications/Xcode.app`.
- [Download Xcode 6.4](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg) from the Apple Developer Download site.
- Mount the `.dmg` and extract `Xcode.app` into `/Applications`.

Comment: It seems that no direct download is available for 6.4, but only for 7 beta

Comment: The link I provided in my answer is directly to `Xcode_6.4.dmg`.

Comment: It won't directly affect what's currently in `~/Library/Developer` and `~/Library/Application Support/Developer`, etc, which is where Xcode stores configuration.  Files in those folders will only change once you start changing the configuration within Xcode.

Comment: In case the download link is dead, refer to other address on [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete /Applications/Xcode.app.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Copy this: `xcode-select --install` and paste it in the terminal
3. Install.
4. After the install has completed, you can see in the App Store that is possible to update your Xcode.

I did that and I can update my Xcode from 6.3 to 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done and worked..Open the Mac App Store, search for the Xcode, check that it shows the latest version and then click install. It will start to downloading and installing the latest version.

Comment: problem, my xcode says latest Xcode 6.4, but my xcode 6.3. and the button only 'Open' no 'Update'.

Comment: You should make all the system updates first. It was very weird to me too, after all the installations of the system's updates the Xcode notified me about its update.