# Updating Xcode 6.3 to 6.4 at time of installing

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I am not able to install xcode 6.4. After downloading now, it's showing this for two hours. I am not able to open xcode and it's not installing also. What can I do? Any idea how to solve this issue?

Xcode 6.3, it asks it can't mount the device since it's running 8.4 version due to this. 
Any suggestions how to solve this?

[Xcode 6.3 not running iOS 8.4 - update to 6.4 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320463/xcode-6-3-not-running-ios-8-4-update-to-6-4-fails)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal. copy this: xcode-select --install
2. Install.
3. After that in App Store you can see that is posible update your Xcode.

I did that and I can update my Xcode from 6.3 to 6.4.