# Qt creator build kits for IOS missing after Xcode 7 upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qt-creator, xcode7

I'm having the same problem as someone on the ESRI forums linked here:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/165647

Namely....

I was building a new deployment for an iPad and through the Apple developer site it requested I accept a new license agreement today. When I downloaded a new provisioning profile it updated Xcode and now the build kits for iOS are invalid in QT Creator.

I can build it just fine in Xcode and deploy to the device it's just the build kits are gone in creator.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem.  I "fixed" it in the follow way:

1) Download the XCode 6.4 dmg (and maybe 7.0 if you need it) from the links on this thread: [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)

2) Install 6.4, using the "keep both" option when you drop it into Applications (next to the broken 7)

3) Rename 7 to "Xcode 7.0".  And 6.4 to plain old "XCode".

Qt should then be able to use the iOS Kit again.

4) After creating a build with Qt, you can later open the project in XCode 7 manually, as needed.

Comment: BTW, Has anybody actually gotten thier QT Project to compile in XCode 7?  I've been fighting with it and made some progress, but still no success...  Currently, I stuck at the error -lz library missing. (I'm using Qt 5.5).  I can probably fix that, but I would just like to know that somebody has seen this work before I pour more time into it.

Comment: I haven't tried the Xcode 7, but now since I was foolish and upgrade my iphone to IOS 9, I can't use Xcode 6.4 anymore. Hopefully this can get solved. I'm wondering if the Qt 5.6alpha is any better.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with a device.  I can't build Qt in XCode 7, so I can't use my iOS 9 device there. I can't use it in 6.4 because it's incompatible now.  I also can't use my iOS 5.1.1 device in XCode 7 because it's simply not compatible with that.  After my "fix" however, I found that I can build and install apps on iOS 9 via Qt Creator.  I just can't launch it from there and see console messages.  I use debug logs written to file though (into the app's documents), and I have uncaught exception handlers directing output there.  That works well enough.

Comment: You can also build iap's and load the app that way via iTunes.

Comment: Tonight I installed Xcode 7. I copied the project directory and renamed all the paths from /applications/Xcode to /applications/Xcode 2/ It then built in Xcode 7. I was able to debug and step through my code in Xcode. I guess I'm stuck here until Qt can fix their Qt creator (hopefully in 5.6??)

Comment: Good to know!  I had all sorts of troubles, but I'm also trying to link several third party libraries.  I am hoping Qt 5.6 plays nice with XCode 7 too!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the best solution, but I was able to get everything working again by deleting XCode, rebooting, time machining Xcode 6.4 back, rebooting.

I think you could get away with just Time Machining, so I don't think you need to delete XCode and reboot before time machining. Just sharing the round about steps I took.

If I find a better answer I will try to remember to update here.

Comment: That's funny. I did the exact same thing. Rolled back to Xcode 6.4 and back in business. Hopefully somebody at Qt will come up with a real answer.