# Xcode 7.0.1 always crashes immediately when open any project

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) and OS X El Capitan

I don't know what happening!
I tried to load new Xcode from Mac App Store
and It also crashes T~T

I can't do any work right now
This is my long crash log I've got when open any project (crashes immediately)

https://gist.github.com/macbaszii/9e45fa13a119670ec20a

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download Xcode ver 6.4 to test your project
[Download Xcode6.dmg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Answer (score 1):

remove all plusgins, and try again.

I also met the same problem, caused by "MCLog".

Comment: Had the same issue. It worked by removing only MCLog.