# Update Xcode 7.0.1 to 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I have a problem in my Xcode and App Store. Recently made an update of my Xcode version 7.0.1 to version 7.1 but this update only downloaded a file 257KB. When I open the Xcode, it is still with version 7.0.1 and when I was in the AppStore to redo the upgrade procedure, Xcode indicates that I already have the 7.1 version installed giving me the option to only open.

I tried to uninstall procedures and installation I found here in the community, but the same thing.

My devices updated for iOS 9.1 and Xcode 7.0.1 not Recognize.

My real problem is the Xcode update. Any help?

Comment: For whatever reason, your Xcode install now has the 7.1 store receipt so the app store thinks all is well.  Best course of action is to trash Xcode AND empty trash then attempt a fresh install from store.

Comment: @WarrenBurton There is no other possible way to solve the problem?

Comment: Not in my experience , once an App Store deployed app gets its weirdness on with respect to receipts  , the best thing is to install clean.

Comment: @WarrenBurton place your answer for me to score as correct. I had to uninstall and then download again. However I had already tried this way and had not worked. Now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, your Xcode install now has the 7.1 store receipt so  `App Store.app` thinks all is well on your machine. Best course of action is to trash `Xcode` AND empty Trash then attempt a fresh install from store.

Its not right but once an App Store deployed app gets an updated receipt without the actual update , the best thing is to install clean.

You must empty trash because the App Store is good at finding receipts.

If you really can't remove the old one for reasons you can delete the `_MASReceipt` folder in the application bundle.

This doesn't remove the need to reinstall the entire thing at some future point.

Answer (score -1):

try to download the .dmg file and re-install XCode with it.

Here you can find a list of all .dmg:
[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)