# Cannot archive an iOS 5.0 era project with RestKit v0.10.3 using Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7, restkit

I have got an old iOS project which is of iOS 5.0 era. I need to archive it using latest iOS SDK and submit it to App Store.

It consists of an `.pbxproj` main project which uses RestKit as sub-subproject. Cocoapods is not being used at that era and [RestKit is being included as git submodule](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule).

Under Xcode 7.2, it builds and runs perfectly fine, but when it comes to archive, it keeps prompting error message like this:

`#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` fails

I have already search RestKit's old documentation and tried using [the suggested method](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting#problem-import-restkitrestkith-fails), but still not working for me.

I wonder if the `Header Search Paths` is set wrongly in build settings, it is set as `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"` originally.

P.S. I do not wish to upgrade the RestKit version. Minimum support iOS version should be iOS 7.

Comment: yes, you most likely need to change the release header paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my problem by setting `Header Search Paths` of targets in all `xcodeproj`s (along the chain, including the parent and child) in `Release` build configuration. I have set the value to `"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Headers"`. I found that the RestKit header files are being copied to `IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Headers` during the archive phase.

Comment: Is anybody knows that is `IntermediateBuildFilesPath` newly added or not? Since which Xcode version `IntermediateBuildFilesPath` being incorporated?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to archiving using old Xcode like 5.0 or prior. Since Xcode 7.2 does not support 5.

Comment: I do not have such an old version of Xcode installed on my machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file

Comment: Use the above link to download the old versions

Comment: It still does not solve my problem as I need to compile and build it using the latest SDK and submit to App Store.

Comment: ok are you using latest rest kit version which supports ios version 8.0 or later?

Comment: is your application has to support minimum ios version is 5.0?

Comment: I do not wish to upgrade the RestKit version. Minimum should be iOS 7.