# How to download latest iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

How can I download iPhone latest SDK? Which version I can use?
I tried from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/
But i don't know whether which version I should download.

Comment: latest version of xCode till date is xCode 7.2. you can download it from here http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2/Xcode_7.2.dmg

Comment: @Madangupta, Only xCode is required?

Comment: Yes, it comes with inbuilt simulator @vipin

Comment: @Madangupta, it will work in windows?

Comment: @VipinKA No it only works in Mac OS X

Comment: @UditS, I developed android app using cordova in windows platform. so can i develop iphone apps in same way? how can i get ios sdk for windows platform?

Comment: I have never used Cordova personally, but you need Xcode running on a Mac system in order to test / run your app in an iOS simulator. This is as per [Cordova iOS Platform guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into the Member center, you can download latest Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Currently, it is Xcode 7.2
and Xcode 7.3 beta, if you are looking for Beta release.

Also you can download the latest Xcode from **Mac App Store**, this ensures that you always get notified of the updates.

There is an amazing Post on SO, that has direct links to all Xcode DMGs.

[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can start development by downloading Xcode 7.2.

[image]

Comment: @VipinKA, yes - the sdk is part of the XCode IDE and will be installed alongwith the same

Comment: Yes you only needs Xcode, Xcode will install simulator for iPhone and iPad along with it.

Comment: @AzeemShaikh, Thank you