# Xcode not showing latest version of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, device

I am currently trying to run my prototype app on my physical iOS device. An error is coming up saying "Could not find Developer Disk." I have come to the conclusion (by looking at other question on stack overflow) that the deployment target does not match the software currently running on my device. The Deployment target allows me to select softwares of 9.2 and older while my device is currently running with the 9.3 update. I have checked that App Store and Xcode does not have an update so I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. To sum it up, I guess my question is:

Why am I unable to select the latest version of software if Xcode is updated to the latest version (According to my information from the App Store and what I am aware of) and how do I fix this error? Is it the Mac? Is it the iPad? Or am I just missing something here.

Any suggestions or input are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Deployment Target allows that version and *later*, not earlier. In other words, if your Deployment Target is 9.2 then your app will only work on iOS devices running iOS 9.2 or later.

Comment: What does "About Xcode" show?  The latest, released, version is *Version 7.3 (7D175)*  This supports iOS 9.3

Comment: The version does say 7.2. How would I update it to the latest version if it is not showing up in the App Store?

Comment: Make sure you have OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) installed and then simply upgrade Xcode via the App Store program.

Comment: How would I get that update as well? It says I also have the latest software on this mac

Comment: Latest version of XCode requires El Capitan.

Comment: First, go to the "" menu and select "About this Mac".  If it doesn't say you are running El-Capitan, then go to the Mac app store and search for "El Capitan" - You can then download this upgrade.  Once you are on El Capitan then you can upgrade to Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You are probably using older version of Xcode.

2.If you can't see updates on Mac AppStore, try searching "Xcode" directly on AppStore search box.

3.If you still can't get update, you can download latest version of Xcode from Apple developer center

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the problem! The update came up when I searched for the app in the app store

Comment: This link also helpfull for download and check latest xcode : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file