# My Xcode 10.0 cannot locate my Iphone SE because its running ios 12.4

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, xcode10

My Xcode 10.0 cannot locate my Iphone SE  because its running ios 12.4. When i try to run an app using my Iphone i get an error saying **"This Iphone SE (Model A1662, A1723, A1723, A1724) is running IOS 12.4 (16G77), which may not be supported by this version of xcode."**

Comment: It’s an old answer, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044362/1271826 outlines how you can build an app and manually install it on an device with newer iOS version. You can’t run it through the Xcode debugger, but at least you can manually run it on your device.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your Xcode version just doesn't have the platform details.

You can verify this for yourself by opening your Applications folder and right-clicking Xcode, choosing `Show Package Contents`, and going to Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport. Here there will be a bunch of folders that are labelled with iOS version numbers. If the folder labelled 12.4 isn't there, there are several ways to solve this:

Download the latest Xcode (You should probably do this and update your system to Mojave).

Then copy-paste the version folder to your version of Xcode or just use the new Xcode. If for some reason you're unable to load the latest Xcode because your system is just that outdated then you can find it on the internet somewhere though I don't recommend this path.

Just FYI:

[Xcode not showing latest version of iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852730/xcode-not-showing-latest-version-of-ios)