# An error was encountered while enabling development on this device

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting "**An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.**" this error message. When i am running the app in my ios device.
please can any one help.

My xcode version is 7.2 And,
My ios device version is 9.2.1

[image]

Comment: I tried many times to reconnect the device, but i get the same error - Mr. EI Captain

Comment: solution : you need to download latest xcode..

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.2 not suport iOS 9.2.1. you need Install updated Xcode
I will suggest to download dmg files Xcode 7.3
[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file)