# XCode 7.3 crashes when editing XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an XCode project that compiles and runs fine but when I add an element to the UI of a particular XIB it crashes XCode when I try to save or when XCode loses focus. Looking at the error data of the crash it seems to be an Assertion Failure relating to an NSTableHeader but I don't understand where to go from there? I am not using auto-layout and this is an OSX app.

```
Process:               Xcode [2505]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.3.1 (10188.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-10188001000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       817226719
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2505]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-06-14 11:30:04.824 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        20048F22-546D-D351-6F8C-D73FF28F4650


Time Awake Since Boot: 67000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7D1014
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-10117/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/ObjectContainer/IBObjectContainer.m:513
Details:  Can't get the OID of an object not in the document: <NSTableHeaderView: 0x7fc5daeefd90>
Object:   <IBObjectContainer: 0x7fc5dae4eeb0>
Method:   -objectIDForObject:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc5d3e17e80>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[IBObjectContainer objectIDForObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4   -[IBDocument objectIDForObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5   -[IBDocument documentArchiver:referenceIDForObject:referenceType:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6   -[IBDocumentArchiver referenceIDForObject:withReferenceType:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObjectReference:referenceType:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObjectReference:referenceType:forKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9   -[NSTableView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 10   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13   __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17   -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibArchiveSubviews:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18   -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19   -[IBNSCustomView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 20   __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23   __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26   -[IBDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27   -[IBDocument archiveAndVerifyArchivingOfTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28   -[IBDocument archivePlatformIndependentDataWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29   -[IBDocument archiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30   -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31   -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32   -[IBDocumentArchiver dataFromArchiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33   __46-[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34   -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35   -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36   -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 37   -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38   -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in AppKit)
 39   -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40   -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:forceTemporaryDirectory:error:] (in AppKit)
 41   -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
 42   -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
 43   -[IDEEditorDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in IDEKit)
 44   __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_22463 (in AppKit)
 45   __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke2460 (in AppKit)
 46   __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_22313 (in AppKit)
 47   __50-[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:]_block_invoke.74 (in IDEKit)
 48   -[NSDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in AppKit)
 49   -[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 50   __101-[NSDocument _fileCoordinator:asynchronouslyCoordinateReadingContentsAndWritingItemAtURL:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_2 (in AppKit)
 51   __68-[IDEEditorDocument continueAsynchronousWorkOnMainThreadUsingBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 52   __62-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _onMainThreadInvokeWorker:]_block_invoke2079 (in AppKit)
 53   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 54   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 55   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 56   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 57   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 58   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 59   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 60   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 61   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 62   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 63   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 64   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 65  0x000000010c51a39b (in Xcode)
 66   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a similar problem, and I think it is because my XIB files are quite old (from XCode 4.6 or older). There was a major change in the xml-schema since then. (See [this article](http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/09/19/upgrade-all-the-xibs/).) I was able to make the change to my XIB I needed to make by fishing XCode 6 out of Time Machine and copying alongside XCode 7 in Applications. I have not attempted to open any projects with XCode 6, but I opened the XIB directly and made the change I needed to make outside the project.

What's weird is that I was able to modify one of these XIB files only a couple of weeks ago. XCode (7) then completely rewrote the XML with the new schema, and it now has no problem editing that XIB. Also, even XCode 6 crashes now if I try to upgrade an XIB to a newer schema. (I guess I can only edit my XIB because XCode 6, unlike XCode 7, can still edit the old schema without upgrading it.)

I think Apple may have introduced a software update in the last couple of weeks that is external to XCode but nevertheless broke the xml upgrade. Or else something else I've done did it, but I can't think what it could be.

FWIW: I'm on 10.11.5, so at least the Interface Builder part of XCode 6 still works on the latest OS.

EDIT: I was able to upgrade the XML and thus be able to edit XIB in XCode 7.3.1 using a slightly more involved solution:

1. Use Fusion or Parallels to create a 10.8 virtual.
2. Install XCode 5.1.1 in the virtual. (You can find download links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file).)
3. Open the XIB in XCode 5.1.1 and upgrade it. You will now be able to open it and save it in XCode 7.

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes sense. My project is several years old and I suspect you're correct about the XML schema changes. Luckily I was able to track my problem down to a NSTableView that I was able to delete and everything seems happy now.