# Unable to update to Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I would like to update to Xcode 8, but when I start the App Store it just shows me an `Open` button, but my existing Version is 7.3.1

The requirements should be El Capitan 10.11.5 - I have 10.11.6 installed.

Why is there no `Update` button?

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: There are lots of questions about xcode installation on SO and a specfic tag for Xcode8....

Comment: Just because there is an Xcode8 tag doesn't mean your question is a programming question. This is no different than asking about updating Numbers or any other program on your computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+installation

Comment: None of that makes your question a programming question. It's still just a generic "how do I update this piece of software?" question.

Comment: Of course not - but there are thousends of iOS Developers that maybe struggle with the same problem. Update not ANY Software, they update their mainly used IDE. Thats a huge different about asking for any other Software. And what next? Wanna tell the other 2700 topic starters in their questions about installation that they are in wrong section? Sometimes i dont know whats the intention for someone to write such things...

Comment: In case if anyone wants to download the latest .dmg from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-file)

Comment: Thanks - still good to know!

Comment: Having the same problem. The question and the answer are useful.

Comment: Thanks. As i thought that i could not be the only one ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if you have multiple installations of Xcode on your system. The App Store often gets confused and loads one you're not considering, such as the version on your back up drive. It's possible it has updated a different installation than the one it launches as well.

Executing the following command in a terminal window should list all installations of Xcode the App Store may find.

`mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.apple.dt.Xcode'"`

When you have Xcode open (from hitting `Open` in the store), right click the Xcode icon on your dock, select `Options`, and `Show in Finder`. Does the installation it shows match up with the one you expected it to launch?

If you specifically open each Xcode installation the `mdfind` command found, are any of them Xcode 8?

You can control which installation of Xcode the App Store will update. Check each of the app folders, and look for a `Contents/_MASReceipt` folder. Ensure the installation you want to update has that (and a `receipt` file inside that), and delete the `_MASReceipt` folder for all of the other versions.

Now the App Store app should update the correct installation for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i have only 1 XCode installation on my mac. When ill run your command, it just shows me /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: Then I would recommend deleting the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/_MASReceipt` folder, renaming `/Applications/Xcode.app` to `/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app`, and then have the App Store download Xcode 8 from scratch. It uses the same amount of bandwidth anyway.

Comment: Thanks - but still the same problem. Ive renamed to app and deleted that folder - but still shows me only "Open" instead of "Update". Any Idea?

Comment: I assume you restarted the App Store app after deleting the folder right? If so, I'd try rebooting the machine. The App Store may be caching the fact it thinks you still have the app.

Comment: Of course ill restartet the App Store App :) - ok thanks i will try that later on. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Fine. After restarting the Mac it works! So now i can have 2 different Versions installed?

Comment: You must be new if you only have two versions of Xcode installed! It's common to keep lots of versions. Especially with Swift changing often. Sometimes you need to go back to an old version. Since Xcode 8 is now final, I `only` have 4 versions installed. I think I've had up to 8 installed at once.

Comment: I had before 6.0 some different Version, was not sure if that is that easy with just renaming ;) Thanks Dave!

Comment: Yep, renaming is fine. Sometimes you'll need to set which version is the main one, using the `xcode-select` command. `xcode-select -p` will show you which is the main installation. `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` sets it. (Change the path there to switch to a different version). This is mainly only an issue if you use the command line tools.

Comment: This was not the cause. See the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

All I had to do was restart my mac.  Then, went to the App Store and saw "Update" instead of "Open".