# Updated to macOS Sierra (10.12.1) and to Xcode 8.1 (8B62) form 7.3.1. Now I am not able to install older versions (both 7.3.1 & 6.4)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-sierra, xcode7.3, xcode8

Recently I updated Mac mini from OS X El Capitan to macOS Sierra (10.12.1). And updated Xcode from Xcode 7.3.1 to Xcode 8.1. Now I looked to install Xcode 7.3.1 and downloaded the dmg file from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. But after installation, it shows that **Cannot install application. Identity of the developer could not be verified.**

How to resolve the issue?

How can I install Xcode 7.3.1 & Xcode 6.4 along Xcode 8.1?

Here are the screen shots when I tried to install Xcode 7.3.1
[image: It appeares when I open it]
[image: At last after some time. It prompt like this]

```
Here is the screenshot of my settings page.
Stystem preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General -> Allow apps download from:
```

[image: Security & privacy - general - download from]

Comment: Not helpful but hint for future updates: before updating Xcode, copy /Applications/Xcode.app to /Applications/Xcode_7_3_1.app to be on the save side.

Comment: I think it may help @shallowThought.. I will try it next time

Comment: Before updating OSX, make sure that you not delete older version of xcode. New version not allow to install older version of xcode

Comment: @GouravJoshi: I didn't do anything anything on the older versions. I just login to Mac AppStore and updated the Xcode. I think that your point is Xcode 8.1 does not allows to install older versions, right?

Comment: No, I think currently we are using beta versions. So that is the possibility that you got these issues. Once public versions are available then may be you will able to fix these issues.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra it shows 10.12.1 is not a beta version.

Comment: Does this occur when you're testing on a device or are you using the simulator?

Comment: @ChrisHaze oh man.. its not about the running. I can't open Xcode 7.3.1 thats the problem

Comment: Just wanted to clarify when you were receiving the explained error - as there is a similar build error that would have a different solution.

Comment: @ChrisHaze: Yeah I got you.. When I double click on the Xcode_7.3.1.dmg file, it appears like in the first screenshot, which is verifying the identity of the developer. Then after a couple minutes later, second screenshot appears.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Sierra and don't plan on it until I push my final test build to iTunes Connect on my latest project. Maybe try downloading another version of Xcode from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sierra has added more security. To enable the *Anywhere* option, enter in terminal

sudo spctl --master-disable

Install Xcode and, if desired, re-enable it immediately afterwards with

sudo spctl --master-enable

Comment: It showed the option "Anywhere". But my issue remains the same. Apple support have no answer for this.

Comment: I done it in terminal and it showed "Anywhere" option. Then I download the Xcode 7.3.1 again and installed. It works, but Xcode 6.3 is not getting installed.

Comment: Also when I open Xcode 7.3.1 and select create a new xcode project, the window appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't run into this scenario with Xcode, this has worked with other outdated software. I believe that if you set your **Allow apps downloaded from:** to *Anywhere* - it should allow you to install and run an older version of Xcode.

Do this by following these steps:

**System Preferences** ~ > **Security & Privacy** ~ > **General** ~ > *( make change )*

In order to make changes you will need to unlock access, click the lock in the bottom left, and then enter your password, and then make the change.

Comment: But in that settings page there is no option for download from anywhere. It contains only two options from appstore and from appstore and identified developers. Wait I will include that screen shot too.