# Telegram not supported Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, telegram, ios-universal-framework

I tried to download telegram source code "http://www.telegramdownload.com/download-telegram-source-codes" and run it using my Xcode 8 but I got the following errors

```
"_BN_rshift1", referenced from:
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BIO_new", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BIO_write", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BIO_s_mem", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_CTX_new", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckMod in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_sub", referenced from:
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_new", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_value_one", referenced from:
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_AES_ige_encrypt", referenced from:
      _MTAesEncryptInplace in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesEncryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesDecryptInplace in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesDecryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesDecrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_num_bits", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_cmp", referenced from:
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_CTX_free", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckMod in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_free", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckMod in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_RSA_free", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_mod_word", referenced from:
      _MTCheckMod in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_bn2bin", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_is_prime_ex", referenced from:
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BIO_free", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_mod_exp", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_AES_set_decrypt_key", referenced from:
      _MTAesDecryptInplace in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesDecryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesDecrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_BN_bin2bn", referenced from:
      _MTRsaEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTExp in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafePrime in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckIsSafeGAOrB in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTCheckMod in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
  "_AES_set_encrypt_key", referenced from:
      _MTAesEncryptInplace in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesEncryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
      _MTAesEncrypt in MtProtoKit iOS(MTEncryption.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and i found that I need to install Universal frameworks but I always get an error

Comment: Found any solution? I’m having similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I'll Add a detailed answer for steps to make it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to make it working:

1. Download an old Xcode , **Xcode 7.x or older**. [this answer will
   help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/1783065) and install it side by side with your up to date
   version.
2. Download [iOS Universal Frameworks](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) and install it using the Old
   Xcode Path. Use the **Real Framework**.
3. Download code from this [unofficial but working version](https://github.com/JohnWong/Telegraph).
4. Open Telegram Xcode Project project file > Telegraph Target > Build Settings > Search For **Header search paths** > MtProotoKit>> make it **recursive**.
5. **DO NOT** accept the solution popup for **POP** framework error that will appear for you. Cancel it and run app regardless this error, it will run successfully.
6. set **appID inside TGTelegramNetworking.m** and Hash and **appId inside TGTelegraph.mm** to yours.
7. Enjoy!

**NOTE:** Take snapshots of your work or commit your repository after each update in project to avoid restarting the whole work if you have done something wrong in any step.

Comment: So this means Xcode 7.x is required, can’t run on Xcode 8?

Comment: No, it's just needed while installation of Universal Frameworks. After it's installed successfully, you will be able to run your app on Xcode 8. It's just a trick as I couldn't install it using Xcode 8.x path