# Can I install Xcode 8.3 on ElCapitan

Tags: ios, xcode8, macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan

Can I install xcode 8.3 without updating my Mac's OS i.e. "OS X El Capitan" (Version 10.11.6)

I was not able to find any reference on Apple's site, However, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/4297260) says I can't.

Right now, I've Xcode 8.2.1 installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the latest version of Xcode (Version 8.3) requires macOS Sierra 10.12. I found this information on the [App Store page](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) under the compatibility section on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's [a challenging way](https://github.com/michalzelinka/Xcode83onElCapitan) to modify and run it. :) Not as your primary Xcode instance, but experiments are possible. :))

Comment: This is the kind of hack I was looking for.