# Apple - iOS - Testing on iOS 10.3 with XCode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a MacBook with **El Capitan** installed on it. I cannot upgrade to sierra! Because of that, **I cannot install XCode 8.3**.

Now I need to test an App with **iOS 10.3** but I cannot build it with XCode 8.2.1 for iOS 10.3. I have an pyhsical device with iOS 10.3 but XCode wont let me run it on that device.

What to do now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing so is still possible with this simple workaround:

1. Download the latest Xcode
2. Right click on the downloaded `Xcode.app`, select Show Package Contents. Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` subfolder
3. Move the `10.3` folder to the identical location in your local Xcode 8.2.1 installation

Comment: I tested it. But i cannot add a new Device with that Version. I think XCode won't let me create a Simulator.

Comment: I also have a physical Device with iOS 10.3. And I cannot choose it in XCode 8.2.1

Comment: This won't allow using a 10.3 simulator in Xcode 8.2.1, but physical devices should work. Works with my 10.3.1 device. Have you restarted Xcode after copying the folder?

Comment: Alright. It works now with my physical device. Better then nothing. Thank you.

Comment: XCode 8.3 asking me to upgrade to swift 3.0 but without swift convert I want to test on 10.3 using XCode 8.2 and its working on physical device. Thank you.

Comment: how i can only `download` the latest Xcode? (the download link in developer apple com only points only to app store where the requirement is macOS 10.12)

Comment: @muescha there is [see more downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) link down the page

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run on a device with 10.3.3 "App installation failed - A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted." Any ideas?

Comment: This gives you the impression that if you copy the correct iOS folder you will see that simulator as an option when downloading simulator runtimes. This is not the case. I've copied the folders, restarted XCode, went to add a device, from there choose download more simulator runtimes... from there I only see 10.2 as the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't get disappointed. There is one way.**

If you have access any of the mac that is running the latest `xcode` and up to date simulators, then navigate to this directory copy the simulators you need and past it on the same directory in your `OSX`.

**You can then be able to run the app on the latest simulator and the updated physical device!**

```
/Applications/Xcode8.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121723/1292061) specifies, iOS 10.3 requires Xcode 8.3 or greater, which in turn requires macOS Sierra.

Comment: damn.. so my macbook is useless now? :/ no way to get xcode 8.3 running on el capitan? :(