# Xcode error “Could not find Developer Disk Image” 10.3.1 Fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I know this question is a duplicate and the permanent solution is to update Xcode to the latest version available.

What I'm looking for is only the developer disk image of every iOS version updates. Developer disk image of every version is less than 15 MB compared to the 4 GB+ download size of Xcode app/.dmg/.xip file.

Stackoverflow is maintaining a thread for links to every version of Xcode.dmg files. 
[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

If I have only the developer disk image, I can run my projects after every iOS updates without re-downloading the entire Xcode or being forced to update the Mac OS version.

Though I acknowledge that running on the latest version of Xcode and Mac OSX is the best practice, sometimes it can also be a problem. Especially if you have slow download speeds and not so reliable Apple download servers with terrible resume support.

My current scenario is something like that. I'm running on 10.11.6 El Capitan and Xcode 8.2. Yesterday I have updated my iPhone 6 to iOS 10.3.1.
Now I have to update the Xcode to 8.3 else I won't be able to run my projects on my device. But to download Xcode 8.3 from Appstore my OSX version should be MacOS Sierra.

My project won't run on simulator due to the SDK's I'm using and now I'm stuck with downloading MacOS Sierra first (5-6 GB) and then Xcode 8.3 (4-4.5 GB) on frustrating 1 Mb/s connection. All of this for a 15 MB file.!

What I want to know is, is there any source or thread in SO that shares these developer disk images and how secure it is to use it (Can this image be tampered?). I don't know whether Apple will provide this option. And I'm equally aware that downloading dev tools from non-trusted sources can get your hands burned (like the developers from China who downloaded modified versions of Xcode outside AppStore or developer.apple.com and got malware in their apps)

Comment: Someone has posted 10.3 developer disk image https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1f7q8w3vgr2ozl/10.3%20%2814E269%29.zip?dl=0>
I'm still looking for 10.3.1 (14E304)

Comment: I am also looking for 10.3.2.

Comment: @ASIMRAZAKHAN : There is no clean way to do this. I got the developer disk image from a friend's mac. 
But its not safe to trust the file uploaded by unknown people. The security risk is high. Once App Store was hit with malware from modified versions of Xcode used by Chinese developers. They downloaded Xcode from 3rd party websites. Same risk is applicable here.

From what I have learned, you will either have to download latest version of Xcode. 
Or copy the disk image from someone you trust. Then again it is a risk.

Comment: i think the developer disk image is used for simulating ios and nothing to do with the code compilation process? How it can infect my ipa? does the DDI is user to create ipa?

Comment: I don't know. There might be a reason Apple is not releasing these disk images separately or they simply want us to be up to date.
As far as security is concerned, I'm not experienced enough to comment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Apple has ever released the developer disk images separately so I can't imagine they would in the future.

Solving the download problem is probably easier, don't use App Store because it's fairly miserable about downloading on a bandwidth limited connection but instead visit `https://developer.apple.com/download/more/`. They have the actual files hosted there so you can get them with a more appropriate tool, you'll know they're definitely from Apple as well.

Comment: Can you recommend me a good way to download dmg/xip files?
I usually use DownThemAll plugin in Firefox for resume support. But always downloading Xcode dmg's are pain in a**... 
Internet Download Manager for windows is very good at resuming if download url is refreshed. Can you recommend me any good alternatives  for mac?

Comment: I just use `rsync` if I can get the direct URL. It'll happily sit in the background and do resume if needs be, doesn't have any issues with .DMG or .XIP.

Answer (score 0):

If some one has download these dmg or than you can use. It will work same as download file. I guess apple did not provide for these disk files seprately. If you want to download Without App Store siera dmg, Xcode.dmg or Xip file.Than check these url. But You should be apple develoeper account.

Siera
https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/macos-sierra-direct-download.html.

For Xcode [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Comment: I'm familiar with with downloading dmg's. In fact I always download .dmg files instead of using the Appstore. Resume support is my problem.