# Can not install XCode on Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave

I am running MacOS 10.14.6 and would like to install XCode into the /Applications folder.

Trying to download it using the Appstore, I get the error message "Xcode can't be installed because macOS 10.15.2 or later is required".

Hence, I downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ the file "Xcode 11.4.xip".

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663097/how-to-install-xcode-from-xip-file) advice, I installed the xip file simply by opening it (Webbrowser -> Downloads -> Open File). This seemed to do something; at least a progress windows told me that the file is being extracted.

However, I don't get any prompt which would offer me a place on where to store the file, but I ended up with a directory `~/Downloads/Xcode.app`. Therefore, was doing a

```
mv ~/Downloads/Xcode.app /Applications
```

Now to test XCode, I went (using the Finder) to /Applications, located XCode.app and doubleclicked it. I got the error message "You have macOS 10.14.6. The application requires macOS 10.15.2 or later".

What can I do to get XCode for my Mac?

Comment: Seems like the problem is how to use a Mac. Try SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: “Hence, I downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ the file "Xcode 11.4.xip"” And that was the very same version of Xcode that the App Store told you _not_ to download.

Comment: Yes, but the App store, which knows what OS version I have, did **not** tell me what version would be the correct one for me. Somehow Apple likes to keep it as mystery, which program version is suitable for which MacOS version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is right, Xcode 11.4 doesn't run on Mojave.

Download Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: This version indeed works. I wished the App Store would have provided me with this information.....

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 11.3.1 from https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.3.1/Xcode_11.3.1.xip

Comment: Above link does not work (says "Unauthorized"... ) unless you arrive at the download (while logged in to your developer account) from this page:(which also has all the other versions): https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: That's not true. You may force 11.4 to run on Mojave but there are problems with debugging ios 14+

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a work around it, the solution is simpler than you might think.

Open the `info.plist` and change the minimum version allowed. You can open the file installing:

```
brew cask install pref-setter
```

**Running 11.5 on Mojave 10.14.6** :

[image]

Comment: Where is the info.plist file?

Comment: @Fadolphin you can find it in right click on xcode and show package content - > content.

Comment: @Niraj after changing it to the Mojave version it still appears `You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode” with this version of macOS. You have macOS 10.14.6. The application requires macOS 10.15.2 or later.`